# pandas - get most recent value of a particular column indexed by another column (get maximum value of a particular column indexed by another column)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   obj_id   data_date   value
0  4        2011-11-01  59500    
1  2        2011-10-01  35200 
2  4        2010-07-31  24860   
3  1        2009-07-28  15860
4  2        2008-10-15  200200
```

I want to get a subset of this data so that I only have the most recent (largest `'data_date'`) `'value'` for each `'obj_id'`.

I've hacked together a solution, but it feels dirty. I was wondering if anyone has a better way. I'm sure I must be missing some easy way to do it through pandas.

My method is essentially to group, sort, retrieve, and recombine as follows:

```
row_arr = []
for grp, grp_df in df.groupby('obj_id'):
    row_arr.append(dfg.sort('data_date', ascending = False)[:1].values[0])

df_new = DataFrame(row_arr, columns = ('obj_id', 'data_date', 'value'))
```

Answer (score 23):

If the number of "obj_id"s is very high you'll want to sort the entire dataframe and then drop duplicates to get the last element.

```
sorted = df.sort_index(by='data_date')
result = sorted.drop_duplicates('obj_id', keep='last').values
```

This should be faster (sorry I didn't test it) because you don't have to do a custom agg function, which is slow when there is a large number of keys.  You might think it's worse to sort the entire dataframe, but in practice in python sorts are fast and native loops are slow.

Comment: This worked a charm, the other answers all had issues for me, and this was also a lot faster.

Comment: This was more than an order of magnitude faster for me than the answer by pdifranc. This question exists in various guises on SO. I'll point them all to this answer. Just one note `FutureWarning: the take_last=True keyword is deprecated, use keep='last' instead`.

Comment: Finding this in 2022 you now need to use `sort_values` instead of `sort_index` as per @Tamelise's answer

Comment: Finding this in 2024! Just to complete the answer:- the `result` is actually a numpy array and so it needs to be converted back to a df. Simply add: `df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['obj_id','data_date','value'])`

Answer (score 18):

This is another possible solution. Dont know if this is the fastest (I doubt..) since I have not benchmarked it against other approaches.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('obj_id').data_date.idxmax(),:]
```

Comment: This is a nice approach that's worked for me in this and other contexts.

Comment: A nice general solution but rather slow compared to some of the other methods

Answer (score 5):

I like crewbum's answer, probably this is faster (sorry, didn't tested this yet, but i avoid sorting everything):

```
df.groupby('obj_id').agg(lambda df: df.values[df['data_date'].values.argmax()])
```

it uses numpys "argmax" function to find the rowindex in which the maximum appears.

Comment: i tested the speed on a dataframe with 24735 rows, grouped into 16 groups (btw: dataset from planethunter.org) and got 12.5 ms (argmax) vs 17.5 ms (sort) as a result of %timeit. So both solutions are quite fast :-) and my dataset seems to be too small ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Updating [thetainted1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007047/12268505) since some of the functions have future warnings now as  tommy.carstensen pointed out. Here's what worked for me:

```
sorted = df.sort_values(by='data_date')

result = sorted.drop_duplicates('obj_id', keep='last')
```

Answer (score 2):

The [aggregate() method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) on groupby objects can be used to create a new DataFrame from a groupby object in a single step.  (I'm not aware of a cleaner way to extract the first/last row of a DataFrame though.)

```
In [12]: df.groupby('obj_id').agg(lambda df: df.sort('data_date')[-1:].values[0])
Out[12]: 
         data_date  value
obj_id                   
1       2009-07-28  15860
2       2011-10-01  35200
4       2011-11-01  59500
```

You can also perform aggregation on individual columns, in which case the aggregate function works on a Series object.

```
In [25]: df.groupby('obj_id')['value'].agg({'diff': lambda s: s.max() - s.min()})
Out[25]: 
          diff
obj_id        
1            0
2       165000
4        34640
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Id': ['00', '01', '02', '02', '01', '03'] ,

'date': ['1990-12-31 ','1990-12-27 ','1990-12-28 ',
         '1990-12-28 ','1992-12-27 ','1990-12-30 '] , 
 
 'Population': ['700','200','300','400','500','100']        
         })
print(df1)

"""
   Id         date Population
0  00  1990-12-31         700
1  01  1990-12-27         200
2  02  1990-12-28         300
3  02  1990-12-28         400
4  01  1992-12-27         500
5  03  1990-12-30         100
"""



Max1 = df1.groupby('Id').apply( lambda df : df['Population'].values[df['Population'].values.argmax()]  )


print(Max1)

"""
Id
00    700
01    500
02    400
03    100
dtype: object
"""

Min1 = df1.groupby('Id').apply(lambda df : df['Population'].values[df['Population'].values.argmin()])

print(Min1)

"""
Id
00    700
01    200
02    300
03    100
dtype: object

"""
```

METHOD 2 :

```
cc = df1.sort_values('Population', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Id'])
print(cc)

"""
   Id         date Population
0  00  1990-12-31         700
4  01  1992-12-27         500
3  02  1990-12-28         400
5  03  1990-12-30         100
"""
```

METHOD 3 :

```
aa = df1.groupby(['Id'],sort = False)['Population'].max()
print(aa)
"""
Id
00    700
01    500
02    400
03    100
Name: Population, dtype: object
"""
```

METHOD 4:

```
res = df1.groupby(['Id'])['Population'].transform(max) == df1['Population']

print(df1[res])

"""
   Id         date Population
0  00  1990-12-31         700
3  02  1990-12-28         400
4  01  1992-12-27         500
5  03  1990-12-30         100
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe to have found a more appropriate solution based off the ones in this thread.
However mine uses the apply function of a dataframe instead of the aggregate.
It also returns a new dataframe with the same columns as the original.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'CARD_NO': ['000', '001', '002', '002', '001', '111'],
'DATE': ['2006-12-31 20:11:39','2006-12-27 20:11:53','2006-12-28 20:12:11','2006-12-28 20:12:13','2008-12-27 20:11:53','2006-12-30 20:11:39']})

print df 
df.groupby('CARD_NO').apply(lambda df:df['DATE'].values[df['DATE'].values.argmax()])
```

Original

```
CARD_NO                 DATE
0     000  2006-12-31 20:11:39
1     001  2006-12-27 20:11:53
2     002  2006-12-28 20:12:11
3     002  2006-12-28 20:12:13
4     001  2008-12-27 20:11:53
5     111  2006-12-30 20:11:39
```

Returned dataframe:

```
CARD_NO
000        2006-12-31 20:11:39
001        2008-12-27 20:11:53
002        2006-12-28 20:12:13
111        2006-12-30 20:11:39
```