# Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

How do I find all rows in a pandas DataFrame which have the max value for `count` column, after grouping by `['Sp','Mt']` columns?

**Example 1:** the following DataFrame:

```
   Sp   Mt Value   count
0  MM1  S1   a     **3**
1  MM1  S1   n       2
2  MM1  S3   cb    **5**
3  MM2  S3   mk    **8**
4  MM2  S4   bg    **10**
5  MM2  S4   dgd     1
6  MM4  S2   rd      2
7  MM4  S2   cb      2
8  MM4  S2   uyi   **7**
```

Expected output is to get the result rows whose count is max in each group, like this:

```
   Sp   Mt   Value  count
0  MM1  S1   a      **3**
2  MM1  S3   cb     **5**
3  MM2  S3   mk     **8**
4  MM2  S4   bg     **10** 
8  MM4  S2   uyi    **7**
```

**Example 2:**

```
   Sp   Mt   Value  count
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd    1
6  MM4  S2   rd     2
7  MM4  S2   cb     8
8  MM4  S2   uyi    8
```

Expected output:

```
   Sp   Mt   Value  count
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
7  MM4  S2   cb     8
8  MM4  S2   uyi    8
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879782/python-pandas-groupby-forloop-idxmax

Could be useful

Comment: This answer is the fastest solution I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21007047/778533

Answer (score 598, accepted):

Firstly, we can get the max count for each group like this:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    Sp  Mt Value  count
0  MM1  S1     a      3
1  MM1  S1     n      2
2  MM1  S3    cb      5
3  MM2  S3    mk      8
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd      1
6  MM4  S2    rd      2
7  MM4  S2    cb      2
8  MM4  S2   uyi      7

In [2]: df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt'])['count'].max()
Out[2]:
Sp   Mt
MM1  S1     3
     S3     5
MM2  S3     8
     S4    10
MM4  S2     7
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

To get the indices of the original DF you can do:

```
In [3]: idx = df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt'])['count'].transform(max) == df['count']

In [4]: df[idx]
Out[4]:
    Sp  Mt Value  count
0  MM1  S1     a      3
2  MM1  S3    cb      5
3  MM2  S3    mk      8
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
8  MM4  S2   uyi      7
```

Note that if you have multiple max values per group, all will be returned.

---

**Update**

On a Hail Mary chance that this is what the OP is requesting:

```
In [5]: df['count_max'] = df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt'])['count'].transform(max)

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
    Sp  Mt Value  count  count_max
0  MM1  S1     a      3          3
1  MM1  S1     n      2          3
2  MM1  S3    cb      5          5
3  MM2  S3    mk      8          8
4  MM2  S4    bg     10         10
5  MM2  S4   dgd      1         10
6  MM4  S2    rd      2          7
7  MM4  S2    cb      2          7
8  MM4  S2   uyi      7          7
```

Comment: @Zelazny7 I'm using the second, `idx` approach. But, I can only afford to a single maximum for each group (and my data has a few duplicate-max's). is there a way to get around this with your solution?

Comment: `transform` method may have pool performance when the data set is large enough, get the max value first then merge the dataframes will be better.

Comment: As @3pitt mentioned, this is wrong for the original question asked.

Comment: @PrakashVanapalli no it isn't

Answer (score 317):

You can sort the dataFrame by count and then remove duplicates. I think it's easier:

```
df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Sp','Mt'])
```

Comment: Very nice! Fast with largish frames (25k rows)

Comment: For those who are somewhat new with Python, you will need to assign this to a new variable, it doesn't change the current df variable.

Comment: @Samir or use `inplace = True` as an argument to `drop_duplicates`

Comment: This is a great answer when need only one of rows with the same max values, however it wont work as expected if I need all the rows with max values.

Comment: @WoodsChen it should work. It keeps the max value per key of [sp,mt]

Comment: I mean if the dataframe is pd.DataFrame({'sp':[1, 1, 2], 'mt':[1, 1, 2], 'value':[2, 2, 3]}, then there will be 2 rows with the same max value 2 in the group where sp==1 and mt==2. @Rani

Comment: @WoodsChen, it drops duplicates of [sp, mt], therefore in your example, the output should be only one row.

Comment: You can address the issue of sort ties by using a different `kind` argument. Look in 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html for more information; some sort kinds are stable.

Comment: this was many times faster with millions of rows than the more readable `.groupby(...).max()` approach.

Answer (score 123):

Easy solution would be to apply the `idxmax()` function to get indices of rows with max values.
This would filter out all the rows with max value in the group.

```
In [367]: df
Out[367]: 
    sp  mt  val  count
0  MM1  S1    a      3
1  MM1  S1    n      2
2  MM1  S3   cb      5
3  MM2  S3   mk      8
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
5  MM2  S4  dgb      1
6  MM4  S2   rd      2
7  MM4  S2   cb      2
8  MM4  S2  uyi      7


# Apply idxmax() and use .loc() on dataframe to filter the rows with max values:
In [368]: df.loc[df.groupby(["sp", "mt"])["count"].idxmax()]
Out[368]: 
    sp  mt  val  count
0  MM1  S1    a      3
2  MM1  S3   cb      5
3  MM2  S3   mk      8
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
8  MM4  S2  uyi      7


# Just to show what values are returned by .idxmax() above:
In [369]: df.groupby(["sp", "mt"])["count"].idxmax().values
Out[369]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 8])
```

Comment: The questioner here specified `"I want to get ALL the rows where count equals max in each group"`, while `idxmax` `Return[s] index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis"` according to the docs (0.21).

Comment: This is a great solution, but for a different problem

Answer (score 79):

You may not need to do `groupby()`, but use both `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('count').drop_duplicates(['Sp', 'Mt'], keep='last')
Out[190]: 
    Sp  Mt Value  count
0  MM1  S1     a      3
2  MM1  S3    cb      5
8  MM4  S2   uyi      7
3  MM2  S3    mk      8
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
```

Also almost same logic by using `tail`

```
df.sort_values('count').groupby(['Sp', 'Mt']).tail(1)
Out[52]: 
    Sp  Mt Value  count
0  MM1  S1     a      3
2  MM1  S3    cb      5
8  MM4  S2   uyi      7
3  MM2  S3    mk      8
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
```

Comment: Not only is this an order of magnitude faster than the other solutions (at least for my use case), it has the added benefit of simply chaining as part of the construction of the original dataframe.

Comment: When you see this answer, you realize that all the others are wrong. This is clearly the way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: One should add `na_position="first"` to `sort_values` in order to ignore `NaN`s.

Comment: I found this to be fast for my DF of several million rows.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with ties.

Answer (score 41):

Having tried the solution suggested by Zelazny on a relatively large DataFrame (~400k rows) I found it to be very slow.  Here is an alternative that I found to run orders of magnitude faster on my data set.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4', 'MM4'],
    'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    'val' : ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
    'count' : [3,2,5,8,10,1,2,2,7]
    })

df_grouped = df.groupby(['sp', 'mt']).agg({'count':'max'})

df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index()

df_grouped = df_grouped.rename(columns={'count':'count_max'})

df = pd.merge(df, df_grouped, how='left', on=['sp', 'mt'])

df = df[df['count'] == df['count_max']]
```

Comment: indeed this is much faster. transform seems to be slow for large dataset.

Comment: Can you add comments to explain what each line does?

Comment: fwiw: I found the more elegant-looking solution from @Zelazny7 took a long time to execute for my set of ~100K rows, but this one ran pretty quickly. (I'm running a now way-obsolete 0.13.0, which might account for slowness).

Comment: But doing this `df[df['count'] == df['count_max']]` will lose NaN rows, as well as the answers above.

Comment: I highly suggest to use this approach, for bigger data frames it is much faster to use .appy() or .agg().

Comment: I am using pandas version 0.25.1 and timed everything in jupyter (extended the lists with `*1000000`). I found the @Zelazny7 solution to be faster. Did I miss something in the test or is it due to the new pandas version?

Comment: This seems overcomplicated, but maybe there's some optimization or prior version limitation I'm not aware of. This works perfectly fine instead: `df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt']).agg({'count': 'max'}).merge(df)[df.columns]`. The `[df.columns]` is only to keep the same column order.

Answer (score 19):

Use `groupby` and `idxmax` methods:

1. transfer col `date` to `datetime`:

   ```
   df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
   ```
2. get the index of `max` of column `date`, after `groupyby ad_id`:

   ```
   idx = df.groupby(by='ad_id')['date'].idxmax()
   ```
3. get the wanted data:

   ```
   df_max = df.loc[idx,]
   ```

```
   ad_id  price       date
7     22      2 2018-06-11
6     23      2 2018-06-22
2     24      2 2018-06-30
3     28      5 2018-06-22
```

Comment: `date` column??? This seems like the answer to a different question. Otherwise, it's a duplicate of [Surya's answer](/a/44960833/4518341) and it has the same problem: in case of a tie, only the first occurrence is kept.

Answer (score 15):

For me, the easiest solution would be keep value when count is equal to the maximum. Therefore, the following one line command is enough :

```
df[df['count'] == df.groupby(['Mt'])['count'].transform(max)]
```

Comment: This is the same solution as [Zelazny7's answer](/a/15705958/4518341). Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 10):

Summarizing, there are many ways, but which one is faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(1000000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

start_time = time.time()
df1idx = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(max) == df['B']
df1 = df[df1idx]
print("---1 ) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
df2 = df.sort_values('B').groupby(['A']).tail(1)
print("---2 ) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
df3 = df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='last')
print("---3 ) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
df3b = df.sort_values('B', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['A'])
print("---3b) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
df4 = df[df['B'] == df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(max)]
print("---4 ) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
d = df.groupby('A')['B'].nlargest(1)
df5 = df.iloc[[i[1] for i in d.index], :]
print("---5 ) %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And the winner is...

- --1 ) 0.03337574005126953 seconds ---
- --2 ) 0.1346898078918457 seconds ---
- --3 ) 0.10243558883666992 seconds ---
- --3b) 0.1004343032836914 seconds ---
- --4 ) 0.028397560119628906 seconds ---
- --5 ) 0.07552886009216309 seconds ---

Comment: Great job including the timer which is missing from all of these suggestions. There are a few more and importantly, it would also be good to add it on a larger dataset.  Using 2.8 million rows with varying amount of duplicates shows some startling figures. Especially using the nlargest fails spectacularly (like more than 100 fold slower) on large data.  The fastest for my data was the sort by then drop duplicate (drop all but last marginally faster than sort descending and drop all but first)

Answer (score 8):

Try using [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) on the groupby object. The advantage is that it returns the rows where "the nlargest item(s)" were fetched from, and we can get their index.

In this case, we want `n=1` for the max and `keep='all'` to include duplicate maxes.

Note: we slice the last (-1) element of our index since our index in this case consist of tuples (e.g. `('MM1', 'S1', 0)`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sp': ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4','MM4'],
    'Mt': ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    'Val': ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
    'count': [3, 2, 5, 8, 10, 1, 2, 2, 7]
})

d = df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt'])['count'].nlargest(1, keep='all')

df.loc[[i[-1] for i in d.index]]
```

```
    Sp  Mt  Val  count
0  MM1  S1    a      3
2  MM1  S3   cb      5
3  MM2  S3   mk      8
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
8  MM4  S2  uyi      7
```

Comment: If the input has a MultiIndex, it might be better to do something more like `df.loc[d.droplevel(['Sp', 'Mt']).index]`. I'm not sure.

Comment: You could do this more idiomatically with `df.loc[d.index.get_level_values(-1)]`.

Comment: this is correct but very very slow on large dataset with ~100k rows.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using this functional style for many group operations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sp': ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4', 'MM4'],
    'Mt': ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    'Val': ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
    'Count': [3, 2, 5, 8, 10, 1, 2, 2, 7]
})

(df.groupby(['Sp', 'Mt'])
   .apply(lambda group: group[group['Count'] == group['Count'].max()])
   .reset_index(drop=True))

    Sp  Mt  Val  Count
0  MM1  S1    a      3
1  MM1  S3   cb      5
2  MM2  S3   mk      8
3  MM2  S4   bg     10
4  MM4  S2  uyi      7
```

`.reset_index(drop=True)` gets you back to the original index by dropping the group-index.

Comment: Instead of `reset_index`, you could consider `.droplevel([0])`, with `.groupby(..., as_index=False)`

Answer (score 6):

Realizing that **"applying" "nlargest"** to **groupby object** works just as fine:

Additional advantage - **also can fetch** **top n values** if required:

```
In [85]: import pandas as pd

In [86]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...: 'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4','MM4'],
    ...: 'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    ...: 'val' : ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
    ...: 'count' : [3,2,5,8,10,1,2,2,7]
    ...: })

## Apply nlargest(1) to find the max val df, and nlargest(n) gives top n values for df:
In [87]: df.groupby(["sp", "mt"]).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, "count")).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[87]:
   count  mt   sp  val
0      3  S1  MM1    a
1      5  S3  MM1   cb
2      8  S3  MM2   mk
3     10  S4  MM2   bg
4      7  S2  MM4  uyi
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with ties.

Answer (score 4):

If you sort your DataFrame that ordering will be preserved in the groupby.  You can then just grab the first or last element and reset the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4','MM4'],
    'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    'val' : ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
    'count' : [3,2,5,8,10,1,2,2,7]
})

df.sort_values("count", ascending=False).groupby(["sp", "mt"]).first().reset_index()
```

Comment: This is practically the same as [Rani's answer](/a/40629420/4518341) and [BENY's answer](/a/54041328/4518341), just using a slightly different method.

Answer (score 3):

Many of these are great answers, but to help show scalability,  on 2.8 million rows with varying amount of duplicates shows some startling differences. The fastest for my data was the sort by then drop duplicate (drop all but last marginally faster than sort descending and drop all but first)

1. Sort Ascending, Drop duplicate keep last (2.22 s)
2. Sort Descending, Drop Duplicate keep First (2.32 s)
3. Transform Max within the loc function (3.73 s)
4. Transform Max storing IDX then using loc select as second step (3.84 s)
5. Groupby using Tail (8.98 s)
6. IDMax with groupby and then using loc select as second step (95.39 s)
7. IDMax with groupby within the loc select (95.74 s)
8. NLargest(1) then using iloc select as a second step (> 35000 s ) - did not finish after running overnight
9. NLargest(1) within iloc select (> 35000 s ) - did not finish after running overnight

As you can see Sort is 1/3 faster than transform and 75% faster than groupby. Everything else is up to 40x slower. In small datasets, this may not matter by much, but as you can see, this can significantly impact large datasets.

Comment: Good guides to performance for those who are using one of these methods!

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4','MM4'],
'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
'val' : ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
'count' : [3,2,5,8,10,1,2,2,7]
})

df.groupby(['sp', 'mt']).apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(1, 'count'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('mt')['count'].idxmax()]
```

if the `df` index isn't unique you may need this step `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` first.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Surya's answer](/a/44960833/4518341) except for the point about a non-unique index.