# Python Pandas groupby forloop & Idxmax

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have a DataFrame that must be grouped on three levels, and would then have the highest value returned. Each day there is a return for each unique value, and I would like to find the highest return and the details.

```
data.groupby(['Company','Product','Industry'])['ROI'].idxmax()
```

The return would show that:

```
Target   - Dish Soap - House       had a 5% ROI on 9/17
Best Buy - CDs       - Electronics had a 3% ROI on 9/3
```

was the highest.

Here's some example data:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----+
| Industry | Product   | Industry    | Date    | ROI |
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----+
| Target   | Dish Soap | House       | 9/17/13 | 5%  |
| Target   | Dish Soap | House       | 9/16/13 | 2%  |
| BestBuy  | CDs       | Electronics | 9/1/13  | 1%  |
| BestBuy  | CDs       | Electroincs | 9/3/13  | 3%  |
| ...
```

Not sure if this would be a for loop, or using .ix.

Answer (score 6):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you could collect the index values in a Series using `groupby` and `idxmax()`, and then select those rows from `df` using `loc`:

```
idx =  data.groupby(['Company','Product','Industry'])['ROI'].idxmax()
data.loc[idx]
```

another option is to use `reindex`:

```
data.reindex(idx)
```

On a (different) dataframe I happened to have handy, it appears `reindex` might be the faster option:

```
In [39]: %timeit df.reindex(idx)
10000 loops, best of 3: 121 us per loop

In [40]: %timeit df.loc[idx]
10000 loops, best of 3: 147 us per loop
```

Comment: It would be cool if max (and friends) accepted a key, in both groupby and df. This would probably still be faster though...

Comment: Yes, I wish `NumPy` had a `key` parameter for `max` and `sort` too! (Though, like you said, it probably wasn't included because calling a Python function for each element of a NumPy array, or DataFrame would be a serious hinderance to speed.)

Comment: I believe this ought to be `data.loc` not `data.iloc`. Atleast this is what worked for me.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk: Thank you very much for the correction. Indeed, it should be `data.loc` since `idxmax` returns labels, not index positions.