# How to get the max value of a multiple column group-by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Iam trying to get the row with maximum value based on another column of a groupby, I am trying to follow the solutions given here [Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-how-can-i-get-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-goups-making-groupby), however it doesn't work when you apply

```
annotations.groupby(['bookid','conceptid'], sort=False)['weight'].max()
```

I get

```
bookid    conceptid
12345678  3942     0.137271
          10673    0.172345
          1002     0.125136
34567819  44407    1.370921
          5111     0.104729
          6160     0.114766
          200      0.151629
          3504     0.152793
```

But I'd like to get only the row with the highest weight, e.g.,

```
bookid    conceptid
12345678  10673    0.172345
34567819  44407    1.370921
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Just a thought, would this give you what you wanted: `annotations.groupby(['bookid'], sort=False)['weight'].max()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need the bookid and conceptid for the maximum weight, try this

```
annotations.ix[annotations.groupby(['bookid'], sort=False)['weight'].idxmax()][['bookid', 'conceptid', 'weight']]
```

**Note:** Since Pandas v0.20 `ix` has been deprecated. Use `.loc` instead.

Answer (score 2):

based on your example of what you want, I think you have too much stuff in your group. I think you want only:

```
annotations.groupby(['bookid'], sort=False)['weight'].max()
```

Answer (score 2):

After grouping we can pass aggregation functions to the grouped object as a dictionary within the agg function.

```
annotations.groupby('bookid').agg({'weight': ['max']})
```

Comment: I think in newer version it should be `annotations.groupby('bookid').agg(weight = 'max')`