# selecting a particular row from groupby object in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
id    marks  year 
1     18      2013
1     25      2012
3     16      2014
2     16      2013
1     19      2013
3     25      2013
2     18      2014
```

suppose now I group the above on id by python command.
      grouped = file.groupby(file.id)

I would like to get a new file with only the row in each group with recent year that is highest of all the year in the group.

Please let me know the command, I am trying with apply but it ll only given the boolean expression. I want the entire row with latest year.

Comment: Be more specific. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: after I group the rows with id, I want the row from each group where the year is maximum

Comment: @MalikBrahimi see the group 1 contains first, second and the fifth row but I need only the first and fifth row in to new file. similarly for group id 2

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is the file a text file? I have an idea as to how it can be implemented with standard Python, as I'm not familiar with Pandas,

Comment: @MalikBrahimi its a csv file imported in to pandas ( dataframe). I am doing it in python only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cobbled this together using this: [Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-how-can-i-get-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-goups-making-groupby)

So basically we can groupby the 'id' column, then call `transform` on the 'year' column and create a boolean index where the year matches the max year value for each 'id':

```
In [103]:

df[df.groupby(['id'])['year'].transform(max) == df['year']]
Out[103]:
   id  marks  year
0   1     18  2013
2   3     16  2014
4   1     19  2013
6   2     18  2014
```

Comment: how can I get the group labels, I mean I want a list {1,2,3} in the above example I had mentioned in the quest

Comment: @Shiva sorry are you talking about this: `df.groupby('id')['year'].max().index`?

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified that the previous comment of mine was a different quest. I mean I want the list of all group labels stored in to a new variable

Comment: So doesn't `labels = df.groupby('id')['year'].max().index` not do what you want?

Comment: yup got it. Thank you  but I need the entire unique group labels. I tried with      labels=df.groupby('id').index    but I am not getting the group labels

Comment: @Shiva sorry I really don't understand what you want for instance `groups = df['id'],unique()` will also give you what you want without needing to perform any grouping, if you are specifically wanting a list then just cast it: `groups = list(df['id'].unique())`

Comment: I have got a doubt in iterating over two lists I wanna clarify can I have ur email id or any sort of way to explain the problem?

Comment: No, if you have another question then please post a new question with as much information as possible I do have a day job ;)