# How to select min record by user in a Pandas data frame while accounting for multiple matches when you only want one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
           record_date           userid        id   priority
1   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     1rhNGfQjU6  2718376     3
2   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     EveMoYR1gs  2718377     3
3   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     iVYGQgU3bX  2718378     3
4   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     adA9fRNIgo  2718379     3
5   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     rCDTlqTOXB  2718380     3
6   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     aBI6JkLyal  2718381     3
7   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     eiEct977ua  2718382     3
8   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     7XVMWZPcZL  2718383     3
9   2016-05-27 02:00:39.600     GHajQM9UXN  2718384     3
```

It's not evident here, but there can be more than one record per user per day. I am trying to find a way to identify the `id` that corresponds to the lowest priority value per user per day. I think I may be having a problem with tie breaking because I tried suggestions from another SO post ([Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)) but that logic would seem to select all records equal to the min, whereas I really need just one (in that case randomly chosen) record with the min priority per user. I know the code above isn't getting that for me because

```
len(set(df[indices]['userid'])) == len(df[indices]['userid'])
```

is False. What's the best way to achieve this? I understand why the code above doesn't work (since it returns `True` for those records equal to the min). What's a good way to break the tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `userid` and date of `datetime` by [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) - get all indexes with minimal `priority` per groups and for select all records use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.record_date)

print (df.loc[df.priority.groupby([df.userid, df.record_date.dt.date]).idxmin()])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'record_date': {1: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 2: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 3: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 4: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 5: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 6: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 7: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 8: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600', 9: '2016-05-27 02:00:39.600'}, 'id': {1: 2718376, 2: 2718377, 3: 2718378, 4: 2718379, 5: 2718380, 6: 2718381, 7: 2718382, 8: 2718383, 9: 2718384}, 'priority': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}, 'userid': {1: '1rhNGfQjU6', 2: '1rhNGfQjU6', 3: '1rhNGfQjU6', 4: 'adA9fRNIgo', 5: 'adA9fRNIgo', 6: 'adA9fRNIgo', 7: 'eiEct977ua', 8: 'eiEct977ua', 9: 'eiEct977ua'}})
```

```
print (df)
        id  priority              record_date      userid
1  2718376         1  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  1rhNGfQjU6
2  2718377         2  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  1rhNGfQjU6
3  2718378         3  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  1rhNGfQjU6
4  2718379         4  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  adA9fRNIgo
5  2718380         5  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  adA9fRNIgo
6  2718381         6  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  adA9fRNIgo
7  2718382         7  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  eiEct977ua
8  2718383         8  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  eiEct977ua
9  2718384         9  2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  eiEct977ua

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.record_date)
print (df.loc[df.priority.groupby([df.userid, df.record_date.dt.day]).idxmin()])
        id  priority             record_date      userid
1  2718376         1 2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  1rhNGfQjU6
4  2718379         4 2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  adA9fRNIgo
7  2718382         7 2016-05-27 02:00:39.600  eiEct977ua
```