# Remove duplicates values on one column in a data frame using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with two columns ID and Salary

```
data = {'ID':[1,2,3,4,2],'salary':[1e3,1.2e3,1e3,2e3,1.5e3]}

+----+--------+  
| ID | salary |  
+----+--------+  
| 1  | 1000.0 |  
+----+--------+  
| 2  | 1200.0 |  
+----+--------+  
| 3  | 1000.0 |  
+----+--------+      
| 4  | 2000.0 |     
+----+--------+      
| 2  | 1500.0 |  
+----+--------+
```

In this data frame some ID are duplicated, ID=2 in this case.
I want to keep the highest salary for each duplicate ID.

```
+----+--------+  
| ID | salary |  
+----+--------+  
| 1  | 1000.0 |  
+----+--------+  
| 2  | 1500.0 |  
+----+--------+  
| 3  | 1000.0 |  
+----+--------+      
| 4  | 2000.0 |     
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more general solution for dataframes with more than two columns in which you want all rows with the max salary per id.

```
data = {'ID':[1,2,3,4,2],'salary':[1e3,1.2e3,1e3,2e3,1.5e3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).assign(more_data=range(5))

df.loc[df.groupby('ID').salary.idxmax()]

   ID  salary  more_data
0   1  1000.0          0
4   2  1500.0          4
2   3  1000.0          2
3   4  2000.0          3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a `groupby` on `'ID'` and take the maximum:

```
df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['salary'].max()
```

The resulting output:

```
   ID  salary
0   1  1000.0
1   2  1500.0
2   3  1000.0
3   4  2000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a duplicate from 
[Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Here's a one-liner:

```
df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['salary'].max()
```

And here's another one:

```
df.sort_values('salary', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID'])
```