# Select and minimum value of a data frame column, by category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame representing IMDb ratings of a selection of tv shows with the following columns:

date, ep_no, episode, show_title, season, rating

I need to select the lowest rated episode of each show, but I am having trouble displaying all of the columns I want.

I can successfully select the correct data using:

```
df.groupby('show_title')['rating'].min()
```

But this only displays the show title and the rating of the lowest rated episode for that show.

I need it to display:
show_title, ep_no, episode, rating

I have tried various tweaks to the code, from the simple to the complex, but I guess I'm just not experienced enough to crack this particular puzzle right now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) is similar to this question; And the following code should do the trick.

```
df[df.groupby('show_title')['rating'].transform(min) == df['rating']]
```

Comment: Thanks, all of the solutions worked, but this one seems to provide the most accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to sort the DataFrame by rating, then dropping duplicates of `show` while keeping the first occurrence of each show:

```
df.sort_values(by='rating').drop_duplicates(['show_title'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# It's easy just do a sort by show_title , rating before using groupby

df.sort_values(by=['show_title','rating'],inplace=True)

# Now use groupby and return the first instance of every group by object
# first row will automatically contain the minimum rating
df1 = df.groupby('show_title').first()
```