# Python Pandas groupby and maximum value of categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
ID  Cat
1   SF
1   W
1   F
2   R64
2   SF
2   F
```

The first column is an identifier and the second column contains categorical data where the order is as follows: `R64 < SF < F < W`

I want a new dataframe that contains for each ID the maximum categorical value. The resulting dataframe should look as follows:

```
ID  Cat
1   W
2   F
```

I tried the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby), but it does not seem to work for categorical data: `df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).Cat.max()`

The result with this approach looks like this:

```
ID  number
1   SF
2   SF
```

I declare the categorical column like this:

```
df['Cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['Cat'], categories = ["R64", "SF", "F", "W"], ordered = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with an extension. Define an ordering in your column:

```
df.Cat = pd.Categorical(
    df.Cat, categories=['R64', 'SF', 'F', 'W'], ordered=True)
```

Now, `groupby` works:

```
df.groupby('ID').Cat.max().reset_index()

   ID Cat
0   1   W
1   2   F
```

Alternatively,  use `sort_values`, `groupby`, and `head`.

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Cat'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('ID').head(1)

   ID Cat
1   1   W
5   2   F
```

Comment: Strangely, for me only the second approach works, even though I use `ordered = True` on the categorical column.

Comment: But the question then becomes: why does `df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).Cat.max()` not work but `df.groupby("ID").Cat.max().reset_index()` work?

Comment: nope, also does not work with `reset_index()`. What works is `sort_values` + `groupby` + `head`.

Comment: @beta, This could be a version issue. In v0.23, I see `as_index` fail versus `reset_index` working.

Comment: @jpp, OP, I've opened a new question on this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778770/weird-behaviour-with-groupby-on-ordered-categorical-columns

Comment: @coldspeed, Thanks, seems like a bug or, at a minimum, an insufficiently documented "feature".

Comment: @beta I foresee this as a bug, so I was watchful to provide you a second solution that I am confident will work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When trying the solution with `reset_index()` I did not see that `as_index=False` was removed. When I remove it (and add `reset_index()`) it works. so both provided solutions work. thanks!