# Weird behaviour with groupby on ordered categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cat': ['SF', 'W', 'F', 'R64', 'SF', 'F'], 
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
})

df.Cat = pd.Categorical(
    df.Cat, categories=['R64', 'SF', 'F', 'W'], ordered=True)
```

As you can see, I've define an ordered categorical column on `Cat`. To verify, check;

```
0     SF
1      W
2      F
3    R64
4     SF
5      F
Name: Cat, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [R64 < SF < F < W]
```

I want to find the largest category PER ID. Doing `groupby` + `max` works.

```
df.groupby('ID').Cat.max()

ID
1    W
2    F
Name: Cat, dtype: object
```

But I don't want ID to be the index, so I specify `as_index=False`.

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).Cat.max()

   ID Cat
0   1   W
1   2  SF
```

Oops! Now, the max is taken **lexicographically**. Can anyone explain whether this is intended behaviour? Or is this a bug?

Note, for this problem, the workaround is `df.groupby('ID').Cat.max().reset_index()`.

Note,

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.22.0'
```

Comment: Note, in v0.23.0, this also works: `df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).Cat.apply(max)`.

Comment: from - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

In the case of multiple keys, the result is a MultiIndex by default, though this can be changed by using the as_index option. 

Since the df was created using two lists, as_index = False, enables the list index, whose comparisons are lexicographic?

Comment: So you're saying the orderer Categorical variable gets lost and is treated as a string when the Multiindex is created? Sounds like a good bug report for pandas. github.

Comment: @smci I want to, but I am so so lazy...

Comment: what about: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()`? It seems to give a good result.

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended behavior, it's a bug.

[Source diving](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e510b1a265fc2ec280cd753ec752a2340c3ffdaf/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L905) shows the flag does two completely different things. The one simply ignores grouper levels and names, it just takes the values with a new range index. The other one clearly keeps them.