# Pandas + groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

The dataset contains 4 columns, where name is the name of the child, yearofbirth denotes the year in which the child was born, number represents the number of babies who were named with that particular name.

```
   For example, entry 1 reads, in the year 1880, 7065 girl children were named Mary.
```

[image: HEAD of dataset]

Through pandas, I`m trying to find out every year which name was the most used one. My code

```
   df.groupby(['yearofbirth']).agg({'number':'max'}).reset_index()
```

The above code partially answers the question in hand.

[image: Result of query]

I want to want the name along with the maximum number.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show your dataframes as text rather than images

Comment: I am unable to see your code. do needful

Answer (score 4):

Based on answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705630/5299969) I came up with this solution:

```
idx = df.groupby(['yearofbirth'])['number'].transform(max) == df['number']
df = df[idx]

print(df)

    name    number  sex yearofbirth
0   Mary    7065    F   1880
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this; `sort` and get the `last` val

```
df.sort_values('number').groupby('yearofbirth').tail(1)
```

or you can use `reindex`

```
df.reindex(df.groupby('yearofbirth').number.idxmax())
```

demo:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name':list('abcaac'),
    ...:                    'yearofbirth':[1800,1800,1801,1801,1802,1802],
    ...:                    'number':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
    ...:                    'sex':['F'] * 6,
    ...: })

In [2]: df.sort_values('number').groupby('yearofbirth').tail(1)
Out[2]:
  name  yearofbirth  number sex
5    c         1802       3   F
1    b         1800       8   F
2    c         1801       9   F


In [3]: df.reindex(df.groupby('yearofbirth').number.idxmax())
Out[3]:
       name  yearofbirth  number sex
number
1         b         1800       8   F
2         c         1801       9   F
5         c         1802       3   F

In [4]: df.loc[df.groupby('yearofbirth').number.idxmax()]
Out[4]:
  name  yearofbirth  number sex
1    b         1800       8   F
2    c         1801       9   F
5    c         1802       3   F
```

Answer (score 2):

I think need if each year have only one maximum value - [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':list('abcaac'),
                   'yearofbirth':[1800,1800,1801,1801,1802,1802],
                   'number':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'sex':['F'] * 6,
})

print (df)
  name  yearofbirth  number sex
0    a         1800       7   F
1    b         1800       8   F
2    c         1801       9   F
3    a         1801       4   F
4    a         1802       2   F
5    c         1802       3   F

df1 = (df.sort_values(['yearofbirth', 'number'], ascending=[True, False])
         .drop_duplicates('yearofbirth'))
print (df1)
  name  yearofbirth  number sex
1    b         1800       8   F
2    c         1801       9   F
5    c         1802       3   F
```

If posssible multiple max values per year use @Teoretic solution.