# How to obtain maximum values from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I created the data in the form of rows and columns from data in a text file using pandas in python. Now, I need to obtain the maximum value of grapes, oranges, and mangos as shown below:

```
       Key       Value
 0     Grapes    50
 1     Oranges   70
 2     Grapes    20
 3     Mangos    10
 4     Oranges   40
 5     Mangos    80
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you already read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) to see if it answers your question?

Comment: Here 0,1,2,3,4,5 is index(row labels) and 50,70,20,10,40,80 is the values and Grapes,Oranges and Mangos are keys.

Comment: kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Comment: I used df.groupby(['Key'], sort=False)['Value'].max() and I got the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=df[df['key']=='orange']
```

So a contains entries of data frame for oranges. Now you can extract the values. 
`val=a['Value'].values`
and find the maximum:
`impprt numpy as np`
`maximum=np.amax(val)`