# pandas groupby, keep only rows with first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

This is a slow solution for what I am hoping to achieve. The problem is performance. Is there a more 'pandonic' way to achieve this without the user defined function? The goal is to keep only all rows that are of the first timestamp that occurs in each group.

```
def get_first_id_time(df):
    first_time = df['datetime'][0]
    df = df.loc[df['datetime']==first_time]

    return df

data = data.groupby('id').apply(get_first_id_time)
```

EDIT: Note, there are many rows with datetime=first_time, for each group.

Comment: use `drop_duplicate(keep=first)`

Comment: You could, in this instance, sort by `id` and `datetime`, then `drop_duplicates` on `id` with param `keep='first'`

Comment: It seems like you simply need `data.groupby('id').head(1)`

Comment: Maybe it is not clear enough - there are many rows that are equal to "first_time". So keeping just the first row does not work.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a [mcve]

Comment: Then this is `transform` + mask with a Boolean Series: `data[data.groupby('id').datetime.transform(min) == data.datetime]`. There's a dup somewhere

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby That's for max, but just change to min (or `first`)

Comment: The comment by ALollz seems most clear and very efficient. If you make this an "answer" to the question I will accept it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just get the `min` datetime and `merge`?

```
min_datetime = data.groupby('id')['datetime'].min().reset_index()

data = data.merge(min_datetime, how='inner', on='id')
```

Edit:

Since there are many rows that have the same `first_datetime`, just `merge` on both `datetime` and `id`.