# How to find maximum within dataset from two grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have two columns Pclass and Embarked. I want to know every class's highest Embarked category.
E. g

```
    Pclass  Embarked
1   C            85
    Q             2
    S           127
2   C            17
    S             3
    Q           164
3   S            66
    Q            72
    C           353
```

PClass 1 highest Embarked in S

PClass 2 highest Embarked in Q

PClass 3 highest Embarked in C

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Comment: Is this a pd.Series or pd.DataFrame?   Do you have multiindex for the index of your dataframe?

Comment: df.groupby(level=0).idxmax()