# How to filter rows in dataframe by biggest date time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to filter the row in a data frame that has different dates for the different fruits, I want to only get the row with the newest date for each fruit.

I'm doing it in python 3.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Fruit':[Melon, Melon, Melon, Apple,Apple], 
    'Date':[203313, 414214, 511515,123223,501010]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Date  Fruit
0  203313  Melon
1  414214  Melon
2  511515  Melon
3  123223  Apple
4  501010  Apple
```

In above example`df`, the correct result would be `Melon, 511515` and `Apple 501010`.

Comment: `df.loc[df.Date.max().index]`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: `df.loc[df.Date.eq(df.Date.max())]`

Answer (score 1):

First, [group dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) on `Fruit` and get `max` value of `Date` and get such row indexes.

> Here's sample code

```
$ipython
In [1]: import pandas as pd
    ...:
    ...: d = {'Fruit':["Melon", "Melon", "Melon", "Apple","Apple"],
    ...:  'Date':[203313, 414214, 511515,123223,501010]}
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    ...:
    ...: df
    ...:
    ...:
Out[1]:
     Date  Fruit
0  203313  Melon
1  414214  Melon
2  511515  Melon
3  123223  Apple
4  501010  Apple

In [2]: idx = df.groupby(['Fruit'], sort=False)['Date'].transform(max) == df.Date

In [3]: df[idx]
Out[3]:
     Date  Fruit
2  511515  Melon
4  501010  Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Fruit').Date.max()
```

Comment: this works, but it dosent show the other columns of my dataframe anymore