# Merge pandas dataframes and remove duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare average revenue "in offer" vs average revenue "out of offer" for each SKU.

When I merge the below two dataframes on `sku` I get multiple rows for each entry because in second dataframe `sku` is not unique. For example every instance of `sku = 1` will have two entries because `test_offer` contains 2 separate offers for sku 1. However there can only be one offer live for a SKU at any time, which should verify the condition:

```
 test_ga['day'] >= test_offer['start_day'] &  test_ga['day'] <= test_offer['end_day']
```

**dataset 1**

```
test_ga = pd.DataFrame( {'day': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 3, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 6, 14: 7, 15: 8, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 3, 19: 4, 20: 5, 21: 6, 22: 7, 23: 8}, 
'sku': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 3, 17: 3, 18: 3, 19: 3, 20: 3, 21: 3, 22: 3, 23: 3}, 
'revenue': {0: 12, 1: 34, 2: 28, 3: 76, 4: 30, 5: 84, 6: 55, 7: 78, 8: 23, 9: 58, 10: 11, 11: 15, 12: 73, 13: 9, 14: 69, 15: 34, 16: 71, 17: 69, 18: 90, 19: 93, 20: 43, 21: 45, 22: 57, 23: 89}} )
```

**dataset 2**

```
test_offer = pd.DataFrame( {'sku': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2}, 
'offer_number': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7}, 
'start_day': {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 4}, 
'end_day': {0: 4, 1: 7, 2: 8}} )
```

**Expected Output**

```
expected_output = pd.DataFrame( {'day': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 3, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 6, 14: 7, 15: 8}, 
'sku': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2}, 
'offer': {0: float('nan'), 1: '5', 2: '5', 3: '5', 4: float('nan'), 5: '6', 6: '6', 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: '7', 12: '7', 13: '7', 14: '7', 15: '7'},
'start_day': {0: float('nan'), 1: '2', 2: '2', 3: '2', 4: float('nan'), 5: '6', 6: '6', 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: '4', 12: '4', 13: '4', 14: '4', 15: '4'}, 
'end_day': {0: float('nan'), 1: '4', 2: '4', 3: '4', 4: float('nan'), 5: '7', 6: '7', 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: '8', 12: '8', 13: '8', 14: '8', 15: '8'}, 
'revenue': {0: 12, 1: 34, 2: 28, 3: 76, 4: 30, 5: 84, 6: 55, 7: 78, 8: 23, 9: 58, 10: 11, 11: 15, 12: 73, 13: 9, 14: 69, 15: 34}} )
```

I did actually find a solution based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705958/2132593), but it took me a while and the question is not really clear.

I thought it could still be useful to create this question even if I found a solution. Besides, there are probably better ways to achieve this that  do not require to create a dummy variables and sorting the dataframe?

If this question is a duplicate let me know and I will cancel it.

Comment: what constitutes a 'real' sku ?

Comment: @Datanovice I have added more context. Hope this helps

Comment: What specific code did you use to produce `expected_output`?

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard()` :) and `print ("test_ga = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(test_ga.to_dict())))`

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you want to merge the two data frames on `sku` but only want the ones where day is greater than the start date and less than the end date. do you have no way to get the actual date? you could merge on `sku` then `date` but the output is quite doable.

Comment: @Giacomo, you mentioned you found a solution based on the linked answer. Could you post that solution? Might be good to have as a benchmark / starting point

Comment: @Datanovice Ultimately what I want to do is to compare average revenue in offer vs average revenue out of offer for the same SKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
test_data = pd.merge(test_ga, test_offer, on = 'sku')
# I define if every row is in offer or not.
test_data['is_offer'] = np.where((test_data['day'] >= test_data['start_day']) & (test_data['day'] <= test_data['end_day']), 1, 0)
expected_output = test_data.sort_values(['sku','day','is_offer']).groupby(['day', 'sku']).tail(1)
```

and then clean up the data adding Nan values for rows not in offer.

```
expected_output['start_day'] = np.where(expected_output['is_offer'] == 0, np.NAN, expected_output['start_day'])
expected_output['end_day'] = np.where(expected_output['is_offer'] == 0, np.NAN, expected_output['end_day'])
expected_output['offer_number'] = np.where(expected_output['is_offer'] == 0, np.NAN, expected_output['offer_number'])
expected_output
```