# groupby: how to show max(field1) and the value of field2 corresponding to max(field1)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a table with 3 fields: client, city, sales, with sales being a float.

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| client |  city  | sales |
+--------+--------+-------+
| a      | NY     |     0 |
| a      | LA     |     1 |
| a      | London |     2 |
| b      | NY     |     3 |
| b      | LA     |     4 |
| b      | London |     5 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

**For each client, I would like to show what is the city with the greatest sales, and what those sales are, ie I want this output:**

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| client |  city  | sales |
+--------+--------+-------+
| a      | London |     2 |
| b      | London |     5 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Any suggestions?

This table can be generated with:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['client']= np.repeat( ['a','b'],3 )
df['city'] = np.tile( ['NY','LA','London'],2)
df['sales']= np.arange(0,6)
```

This is wrong because it calculates the 'maximum' of the city, and shows NY because it considers that N > L

```
max_by_id = df.groupby('client').max()
```

**I can first create a dataframe with the highest sales, and then merge it with the initial dataframe to retrieve the city; it works, but I was wondering if there is a faster / more elegant way?**

```
out = pd.merge( df, max_by_id, how='inner' ,on=['client','sales'] )
```

I remember doing something similar with cross apply statements in SQL but wouldn't know how to run a Pandas equivalent.

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('client')['sales'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the logic behind this? Does it work also if I have other fields I want to retrieve?

Comment: I get an AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 622, in wrapper
    raise ValueError on my real data which I cannot replicate in the toy example. Mmm...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous checkout my answer. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort by `sales` and then `groupby` `client` and pick [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)

```
df.sort_values(['sales'], ascending=False).groupby('client').first().reset_index()
```

**OR**

As @user3483203:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('client')['sales'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
 client city    sales
0   a   London  2
1   b   London  5
```

Comment: sorting is O(n log n); idxmax is O(n). The solution in the comment is more efficient

Comment: Right! added to the answer. @Marat

Comment: `.head(1)` (or .drop_duplicates instead of groupby)  in the first case. first might not return values from the same row with missing data.