# groupby with idxmax is not giving me required output?

Tags: python

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   volume  Stockname
0   2017-09-01  250.00  255.00  237.50  237.50  4658997 ABCAPITAL
1   2017-09-04  225.65  225.65  225.65  225.65  309923  ABCAPITAL
2   2017-09-05  214.40  214.40  214.40  214.40  192377  ABCAPITAL
3   2017-09-06  203.70  203.70  203.70  203.70  267160  ABCAPITAL
4   2017-09-07  193.55  213.85  193.55  206.95  34241770    ABCAPITAL
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1046    2020-03-26  125.05  133.15  119.00  128.75  12044426    ZEEL
1047    2020-03-27  132.00  138.65  127.00  128.05  8765500 ZEEL
1048    2020-03-30  122.30  135.00  122.30  125.65  8707583 ZEEL
1049    2020-03-31  130.50  130.65  123.00  123.95  8733424 ZEEL
1050    2020-04-01  124.00  126.75  120.00  120.90  6571551 ZEEL
```

So I have this dataframe which has multiple stocks and O,H,L,C data

I want to create a new dataframe which has max closing price for each stock. I want the complete line item for this purpose

Here is my code

```
x = new.groupby('Stockname')
new.loc[x['Close'].idxmax()]
```

Output which is coming is totally wrong. The closing prices are not max for each stock. Kindly help me with this

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   volume  Stockname
0   2017-09-01  250.00  255.00  237.50  237.50  4658997 ABCAPITAL
0   2016-01-01  233.00  263.45  232.00  248.00  307528  ABFRL
0   2016-01-01  1362.00 1380.40 1360.00 1373.65 161982  ACC
0   2016-01-01  261.00  268.30  260.10  267.55  1347893 ADANIPORTS
0   2016-01-01  32.50   34.40   32.30   34.00   12331921    ADANIPOWER
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
506 2018-01-16  232.90  237.20  229.20  233.00  1198721 VGUARD
506 2018-01-16  635.00  639.95  618.50  623.05  921801  VOLTAS
506 2018-01-16  1529.95 1538.65 1499.00 1507.75 18023   WHIRLPOOL
506 2018-01-16  238.27  251.13  237.59  249.59  6166445 WIPRO
506 2018-01-16  610.40  618.30  607.50  613.40  4805427 ZEEL
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Comment: I did the exact same thing but not getting the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gave me what you are after:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['Stockname'])['Close'].transform(max) == df['Close']]
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Stockname')['Close'].idxmax()]
```

Or:

```
df = df.sort_values('Close', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Stockname')
```

Indeed, as per @jcaliz in comment mentioned, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705958/9758194) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44960833/9758194) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40629420/9758194). All boiled down to result below:

---

```
          Date    Open    High    Low   Close    volume  Stockname
0   2017-09-01  250.00  255.00  237.5  237.50   4658997  ABCAPITAL
506 2020-03-26  125.05  133.15  119.0  128.75  12044426       ZEEL
```

---

If this has worked please give credit to the original posters, I merely copied over working code.

Comment: Yes, I saw this solution. Can't this be done through idxmax () ?

Comment: Yes, even I used the same code before -  df = df.loc[df.groupby('Stockname')['Close'].idxmax()]  & its not working. I posted the output to this code above. Not sure why

Comment: Have you tried it in a single line like I showed? @Josepharasta. Worked totally fine for me. Your two line approach however, didn't

Comment: Yes, i tried the same one liner and still not working. Not sure why

Comment: Okay, I will use transform feature then. Thanks Jvdv for your help. Upvoting this

Comment: @Josepharasta, I can't think of why it wouldn't have worked for you. I merely copied your data and applied `idxmax` and it worked.