# Calculation in python using loops for rainfall application

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am trying to compute for the “maximum rainfall” in different durations, say, “1hr” and “3hr” duration.

Using my dataset:

```
Date                                  Rainfall
2007-01-01 00:00:00                       0 
2007-01-01 01:00:00                      0.5    
2007-01-01 02:00:00                      0.9
2007-01-01 03:00:00                      0.2
…..
2009-01-01 00:00:00                       0 
2009-01-01 01:00:00                      0.4    
2009-01-01 02:00:00                      0.8
2009-01-01 03:00:00                      0.9
```

If I will set my date range (e.g. 2007-01-01 to 2009-01-01), and I specify it to be maximum “3hr” duration, the computation should look like this (this should be in a for loop, I guess):

Starting at `2007-01-01 00:00:00` , the maximum 3hr is :

```
0+0.5+0.9=1.4
```

Then starting at `2007-01-01 01:00:00` , the maximum 3hr is :

```
0.5+0.9+0.2=1.6
```

And so on… until it finds the real maximum 3hr duration when it reach 2009-01-01 03:00:00.

I know this needs to have a for loop, I am new to python so I’m still learning. Anyone who can help me shed light about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `DatetimeIndex` and frequence `3H` with `sum`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.set_index('Date').rolling('3H').sum()
print (df1)
                     Rainfall
Date                         
2007-01-01 00:00:00       0.0
2007-01-01 01:00:00       0.5
2007-01-01 02:00:00       1.4
2007-01-01 03:00:00       1.6
```

If need maximum per 3 hours:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Date').rolling('3H').max()
print (df2)
                     Rainfall
Date                         
2007-01-01 00:00:00       0.0
2007-01-01 01:00:00       0.5
2007-01-01 02:00:00       0.9
2007-01-01 03:00:00       0.9
```

Comment: but unfortunately, due to the large data sets I have, rolling sum seems unable to handle it. the data frame itself doesnt load..

Comment: @karate - What is number of rows in file? What is your code for load DataFrame? Because I have no experience problem with load DataFrame.

Comment: hi, I was able to do the rolling sum once i transform it to csv. however, if i want the rolling sum to be per Year, what should I add in the code?

Comment: @karate - Do you think change `.rolling('3H')` to `.rolling('Y')` ?

Comment: no. i'm planning to still use rolling sum every 3 hours. But the highest 3 hour rolling sum per year will be my output..

Comment: @karate - So need `df1 = df.set_index('Date').rolling('3H').sum()
df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby(df1.index.year)['Rainfall'].idxmax()]` ?

Comment: can you explain what idxmax () is for?

Comment: @karate - It return one maximal row per year, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705630)