# Resampling for multiple years in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have data for all days for multiple years (over a 10 year period from 2004 to 2014). I want to find the max and min for this period for all days in the 10 years eg. What is the max for Jan 1 for all years between 2004 and 2014. How would I do this using resample in pandas?
[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k1Bm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2014-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Max': range(len(rng))})  
print (df)
           Date   Max
0    2004-01-01     0
1    2004-01-02     1
2    2004-01-03     2
3    2004-01-04     3
4    2004-01-05     4
        ...   ...
4013 2014-12-27  4013
4014 2014-12-28  4014
4015 2014-12-29  4015
4016 2014-12-30  4016
4017 2014-12-31  4017

[4018 rows x 2 columns]
```

First convert column `Date` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then create custom format `MM-DD` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and last aggregate `max`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#if necessary sorting
#df = df.sort_values('Date')
md = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%d')
df = df.groupby(md, sort=False)['Max'].max().reset_index()
print (df)
       Date   Max
0    Jan-01  3653
1    Jan-02  3654
2    Jan-03  3655
3    Jan-04  3656
4    Jan-05  3657
..      ...   ...
361  Dec-27  4013
362  Dec-28  4014
363  Dec-29  4015
364  Dec-30  4016
365  Dec-31  4017

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks you @jezrael, I will not post images to SO (new here). The above code doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I had to change the line to "df['md'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%d')" i.e. add md as a column and this worked for me. I don't know why the earlier solution wasn't working but this seems to be working perfectly, thank you. Also, what would be the best way to learn data manipulation using pandas and for dates/datetimes?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this if you want to have the original dates associated to the max and min values (based on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("2004-01-01", freq="D", periods=5000),
                   "value": np.random.randint(0,100,5000)})
df["day"] = df.date.dt.day
df["month"] = df.date.dt.month
df = df.set_index("date")
idx = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value'].transform(max) == df['value']
max_df = df[idx].sort_values(["month", "day"])
idx = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value'].transform(min) == df['value']
min_df = df[idx].sort_values(["month", "day"])
```

And the result is for instance for `max_df` :

```
           value  day  month
date                         
2010-01-01     88    1      1
2008-01-02     88    2      1
2011-01-03     94    3      1
2009-01-04     98    4      1
2004-01-05     98    5      1
```

You can have multiple rows for same day and month if there are several maxima.