# Data in a pandas DataFrame comes out at the wrong index position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the code bellow each 'Person' has a corresponding 'Sales' value , but when I execute `print(compData.max())` 'Vanessa' gets the value of '340' which in the initial 'df' belongs to 'Amy'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Company':['GOOG','GOOG','MSFT','MSFT','FB','FB'],
       'Person':['Sam','Charlie','Amy','Vanessa','Carl','Sarah'],
       'Sales':[200,120,340,124,243,350]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

compData = df.groupby('Company')

print(df)
print(compData.max())
print(df.loc[3])
```

Here is the output :

```
  Company   Person  Sales
0    GOOG      Sam    200
1    GOOG  Charlie    120
2    MSFT      Amy    340
3    MSFT  Vanessa    124
4      FB     Carl    243
5      FB    Sarah    350
          Person  Sales
Company                
FB         Sarah    350
GOOG         Sam    200
MSFT     Vanessa    340

Company       MSFT
Person     Vanessa
Sales          124
```

Also when I execute `print(df.loc[3])` 'Vanessa' gets the right value

Comment: Use `compData = df.groupby('Company').max()

    print(compData.iloc[2])`

Comment: that `groupby.max()` returns the max value per group for each column. for group `MSFT` the max of `Person` is `Vanessa` and max for `Sales` is `340`. `Vanessa` is max because of "bigger" beginning letter

Comment: why would you close my question ? That doesn't answer my question . ```print(comData.iloc[2])``` bring up again 'Vanessa' with the wrong value of 340 .

Comment: @jezrael I think the author is wondering why Vanessa has the value 340 for that groupby. i dont think the problem is about the indexing

Comment: @luigigi Thanks so much that makes perfect sense

Comment: @luigigi - oops, reopened.

Comment: This is duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add an alternate solution to Pibe_chorro's answer which gives you directly the maximum sales and sales person per company including the original index:

```
compData.apply(lambda x: x[x.Sales == x.Sales.max()]).reset_index(level=[0])
```

which gives you:

```
    Company Person  Sales
5        FB  Sarah  350
0      GOOG    Sam  200
2      MSFT    Amy  340
```

You can sort by the index if needed using the [pd.DataFrame.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

```
compData.apply(lambda x: x[x.Sales == x.Sales.max()]).reset_index(level=[0]).sort_index()
```

which results:

```
    Company Person  Sales
0      GOOG    Sam  200
2      MSFT    Amy  340
5        FB  Sarah  350
```

Answer (score 0):

As luigigi pointed out, `groupby.max()` returns the maximum value for each column.

To get what you want you can search for the index with the max value in `'Sales'` like this:

```
idx = df.groupby('Company')['Sales'].transform(max) == df['Sales']
print (df[idx])

Company Person  Sales
0    GOOG    Sam    200
2    MSFT    Amy    340
5      FB  Sarah    350
```

stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

maybe there is an easier way, but thats what I found