# Pandas: get Item ID of the most popular in a category (two Groupby level)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry that I cannot think of a title.

I have a DF like this:

| item_cat1 | item_id | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| C | 4 | 2 |

I want to get the item that is the most popular among the item category `item_cat1`. This is the desired output:

| item_cat1 | item_id | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 4 | 2 |

Explanation: in item_cat1 A, item_id `3` is sold the most (4) compares to item_id `1` (2).

I tried `train.groupby(["item_cat1", "item_id"])["item_count"].sum()`, but I don't know how to choose only the max value.

P/S: what I want is the `item_id`, not the `item_count`. This answer does not help me: [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Comment: Dupe answer `train.loc[train.groupby(["item_cat1"])["item_count"].idxmax()]` not working?

Comment: If not working, can you add more data for see how `train.loc[train.groupby(["item_cat1"])["item_count"].idxmax()]` failed? Now in sample data working very well

Comment: Thank you, it works! It is my bad that the DF can contain NaNs.

Comment: Super! Happy coding!