# Pandas groupby max with a custom key/comparison function

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array like this:

```
name  foo     bar
   A    0  [3, 1]
   A    2  [2, 3] *
   B    3  [1, 0]
   B    9  [0, 1] *
   B    1  [1, 0]
```

I would like to keep, for each unique `name`, the row that hax the maximum `bar[1]` value (marked with a `*` above), so that the result should be

```
name  foo     bar
   A    2  [2, 3]
   B    9  [0, 1]
```

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) and the related answer that is very closely related to my problem, however in that question, the `max` is done directly on the columns value. If `GroupBy.max` accepted a `key` function like the built-in `max` then this would be a no-brainer -- however this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indexing by `str` for select second value of lists and pass to [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices and select by `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.bar.str[1].groupby(df['name']).idxmax()]
```