# How do I Find max value of a particular column between 2 dates based on a condition from another column in python

Tags: python

Can I get some help on how to Find max value of a particular column between 2 dates based on a condition from another column."

I have a df like below and I would need to find the max value in the rows in-between  where conditions are - max value of ['high'] column between the 2 'act' value in the ['mark'] column within the same ['symbol'] and store the value in a new column.

i.e. find max of high for APPLE between 04/03/2021 and  09/03/2021 as both these dates have "act" in the mark column. [ there are more 'act' marked in the column, but due to space constrain share a short version here ]

similarly for orange  between 04/03/2021 and  10/03/2021.

It should not do this calculation for the "act" marker for Apple on 09 as there is no more act for apple after that.

Data:

| date | symbol | open | high | low | close | mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/03/2021 | APPLE | 732 | 754.95 | 723.4 | 729.85 |  |
| 04/03/2021 | APPLE | 733.25 | 765.7 | 715.85 | 752.45 | act |
| 05/03/2021 | APPLE | 752.45 | 761 | 730.5 | 748.95 |  |
| 08/03/2021 | APPLE | 762.7 | 767.8 | 744.2 | 748.4 |  |
| 09/03/2021 | APPLE | 755.55 | 759.4 | 738.65 | 750.75 | act |
| 10/03/2021 | APPLE | 757.5 | 753.1 | 743 | 745.35 |  |
| 12/03/2021 | APPLE | 743 | 752.1 | 723 | 728.15 |  |
| 15/03/2021 | APPLE | 727.8 | 727.8 | 706.05 | 719.05 |  |
| 03/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2406 | 2417.7 | 2375.8 | 2402.1 |  |
| 04/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2380 | 2435 | 2350 | 2417.1 | act |
| 05/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2399 | 2423.9 | 2377.1 | 2387.1 |  |
| 08/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2383 | 2413.5 | 2360.05 | 2382.7 |  |
| 09/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2400 | 2444 | 2396.15 | 2422.7 |  |
| 10/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2446 | 2446 | 2415.55 | 2431.95 | act |
| 12/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2442.8 | 2464.65 | 2397 | 2401.35 |  |
| 15/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2402.55 | 2427.55 | 2343.05 | 2355 |  |

Comment: What answers are you looking for here, is it right to say you'd expect high for APPLE to be 767.8 on the 8th March? Where do you want this number in the new column in this dataframe, or do you want an extract that returns just the values (2 in this case) that you want as a separate table?

Comment: Thank you for asking.
I expect high for APPLE to be 767.8 to be in a new column on the row of 04/03/2021. idea being that between the 2 "act" marked date the highest value it reach was 767.8.

Comment: OK, it's an interesting problem - what things have you tried so far, and what sorts of volumes are you looking at here? A solution for a few thousand rows might look different to a solution for many millions of rows.

Comment: I tried using the info in this link but did not take me ahead much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

the size of the data would be within 1 to 2  million rows at max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've taken a crack at this - first I recreated the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data={("03/03/2021","APPLE",732,754.95,723.4,729.85,), 
      ("04/03/2021","APPLE",733.25,765.7,715.85,752.45,"act"), 
      ("05/03/2021","APPLE",752.45,761,730.5,748.95,), 
      ("08/03/2021","APPLE",762.7,767.8,744.2,748.4,), 
      ("09/03/2021","APPLE",755.55,759.4,738.65,750.75,"act"), 
      ("10/03/2021","APPLE",757.5,753.1,743,745.35,), 
      ("12/03/2021","APPLE",743,752.1,723,728.15,), 
      ("15/03/2021","APPLE",727.8,727.8,706.05,719.05,), 
      ("03/03/2021","ORANGE",2406,2417.7,2375.8,2402.1,), 
      ("04/03/2021","ORANGE",2380,2435,2350,2417.1,"act"), 
      ("05/03/2021","ORANGE",2399,2423.9,2377.1,2387.1,), 
      ("08/03/2021","ORANGE",2383,2413.5,2360.05,2382.7,), 
      ("09/03/2021","ORANGE",2400,2444,2396.15,2422.7,), 
      ("10/03/2021","ORANGE",2446,2446,2415.55,2431.95,"act"), 
      ("12/03/2021","ORANGE",2442.8,2464.65,2397,2401.35,), 
      ("15/03/2021","ORANGE",2402.55,2427.55,2343.05,2355,)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                  columns=("date","symbol","open","high","low","close","mark")).
                  sort_values(by=["symbol", "date"]).fillna("").reset_index(drop=True)
```

I figure that what you want to do is a simple `max` on group-by. The tricky part is manipulating your data so it conforms with what group-by expects. That is, a field on which to group.

```
def block_diff(series, trigger, start_stop=False):
    toggle = False
    rs = list()
    for i,v in series.iteritems():
        if v==trigger:
            if start_stop and toggle:
                rs.append(toggle)
                toggle=not toggle
            elif start_stop and not toggle:
                toggle=not toggle
                rs.append(toggle)
            elif not start_stop:
                toggle=not toggle
                rs.append(toggle)
        else:
            rs.append(toggle)
    return pd.Series(rs)
```

So the above function is defined - the idea here is that we want to *block-out* the regions that are going to feature in the group-by. This function accepts a series, some matching trigger value, and a start_stop flag to fine-tune behavior.

If I apply that to the dataframe, using the returned `True/False` values as an index to populate a copy of the grouping variable and store the results in a new field called `act_block` then I create a unique grouping field that also functions as a start-stop filter. At the same time, I also create an additional column called `act_sequence` which we'll use later to identify the initial starting row for each sub-group.

```
df['act_block'] = df[block_diff(df['mark'], "act", True)]['symbol']
df['act_sequence'] = df.groupby("act_block").cumcount()
df

    date        symbol  open    high    low     close   mark    act_block   act_sequence
0   03/03/2021  APPLE   732.00  754.95  723.40  729.85          NaN         0
1   04/03/2021  APPLE   733.25  765.70  715.85  752.45  act     APPLE       0
2   05/03/2021  APPLE   752.45  761.00  730.50  748.95          APPLE       1
3   08/03/2021  APPLE   762.70  767.80  744.20  748.40          APPLE       2
4   09/03/2021  APPLE   755.55  759.40  738.65  750.75  act     APPLE       3
5   10/03/2021  APPLE   757.50  753.10  743.00  745.35          NaN         1
6   12/03/2021  APPLE   743.00  752.10  723.00  728.15          NaN         2
7   15/03/2021  APPLE   727.80  727.80  706.05  719.05          NaN         3
8   03/03/2021  ORANGE  2406.00 2417.70 2375.80 2402.10         NaN         4
9   04/03/2021  ORANGE  2380.00 2435.00 2350.00 2417.10 act     ORANGE      0
10  05/03/2021  ORANGE  2399.00 2423.90 2377.10 2387.10         ORANGE      1
11  08/03/2021  ORANGE  2383.00 2413.50 2360.05 2382.70         ORANGE      2
12  09/03/2021  ORANGE  2400.00 2444.00 2396.15 2422.70         ORANGE      3
13  10/03/2021  ORANGE  2446.00 2446.00 2415.55 2431.95 act     ORANGE      4
14  12/03/2021  ORANGE  2442.80 2464.65 2397.00 2401.35         NaN         5
15  15/03/2021  ORANGE  2402.55 2427.55 2343.05 2355.00         NaN         6
```

Now we can do a simple groupby on `act_block`, saving the results into a series called max_groups:

```
max_groups = df.groupby("act_block")["high"].max()


act_block
APPLE      767.8
ORANGE    2446.0
Name: high, dtype: float64
```

Take this series and merge it with the original dataframe - if we do this with a filter, the `max_vals` object will inherit the original dataframe's index, allowing us to do a `pd.concat` to selectively join the two objects together to produce the intended output.

```
max_vals = df.merge(max_groups, left_on=["act_block"], right_on="act_block",how="left")[(df['act_sequence']==0)].fillna("")['high_y']
max_vals.name="max_val"
new_df = pd.concat([df, max_vals], axis=1).fillna("")
new_df = new_df[["date","symbol","open","high","low","close","mark","max_val"]]

new_df
```

|  | date | symbol | open | high | low | close | mark | max_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 03/03/2021 | APPLE | 732.00 | 754.95 | 723.40 | 729.85 |  |  |
| 1 | 04/03/2021 | APPLE | 733.25 | 765.70 | 715.85 | 752.45 | act | 767.8 |
| 2 | 05/03/2021 | APPLE | 752.45 | 761.00 | 730.50 | 748.95 |  |  |
| 3 | 08/03/2021 | APPLE | 762.70 | 767.80 | 744.20 | 748.40 |  |  |
| 4 | 09/03/2021 | APPLE | 755.55 | 759.40 | 738.65 | 750.75 | act |  |
| 5 | 10/03/2021 | APPLE | 757.50 | 753.10 | 743.00 | 745.35 |  |  |
| 6 | 12/03/2021 | APPLE | 743.00 | 752.10 | 723.00 | 728.15 |  |  |
| 7 | 15/03/2021 | APPLE | 727.80 | 727.80 | 706.05 | 719.05 |  |  |
| 8 | 03/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2406.00 | 2417.70 | 2375.80 | 2402.10 |  |  |
| 9 | 04/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2380.00 | 2435.00 | 2350.00 | 2417.10 | act | 2446 |
| 10 | 05/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2399.00 | 2423.90 | 2377.10 | 2387.10 |  |  |
| 11 | 08/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2383.00 | 2413.50 | 2360.05 | 2382.70 |  |  |
| 12 | 09/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2400.00 | 2444.00 | 2396.15 | 2422.70 |  |  |
| 13 | 10/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2446.00 | 2446.00 | 2415.55 | 2431.95 | act |  |
| 14 | 12/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2442.80 | 2464.65 | 2397.00 | 2401.35 |  |  |
| 15 | 15/03/2021 | ORANGE | 2402.55 | 2427.55 | 2343.05 | 2355.00 |  |  |

Comment: Firstly, a big thank you for taking the time out for this. Since I am a beginner, I am a bit overwhelmed looking at this, but I am positive I will be able to grasp this with a little time. I do see the your output result just the way I need it to be.

Again, cant thank you enough.

Kind regards
Dhriti

Comment: You're welcome - I think it's an interesting question because it combines 3 or 4 operations that would normally be relatively straightforward on their own, but this problem requires combining them in an interesting way. As you try it out, take a look at the intermediate dataframes/objects etc - which should help understanding what's happening at each stage.