# How to remove duplicate values from the column with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Had a dataset like :

```
mail id          score
xyz@yahoo.com     10
abc@gmail.com     13
xyz@yahoo.com     16
pqr@gmail.com     20
abc@gmail.com     19
mno@gmail.com     24
```

From the above data, have to remove duplicate values by comparing the score column.

Eg: In mail column we have 2 xyz@yahoo.com and abc@gmil.com. Here, we need remove duplicate values by comparing there score.

For xyz@yahoo.com had score 10 & 16 then it should return the greate value row.

output:

```
mail id          score
xyz@yahoo.com     16
pqr@gmail.com     20
abc@gmail.com     19
mno@gmail.com     24
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort_values()` method and `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
resultdf=df.sort_values('score',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('mail id')
```

**OR**

You can also do this by `groupby()` method:

```
resultdf=df.groupby('mail id')['score'].nlargest(1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

Comment: yop, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40629420/2901002

Comment: only difference is drop_duplicates by 2 columns

Comment: ohh...didn't noticed Thnx again @jezrael **:)**

Comment: ya, best remove, but it is up to you