# Pandas group by using for loop, editing, then combining

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have the following Table

```
      time                   userid   market   device    query      querytype   browser
0     2020-07-01  04:47:21   A        EN-US    PC        WEATHER    WEATHER     EDGE
1     2020-07-01  07:23:52   C        ZH-CN    MOBILE    RECIPIES   FOOD        SAFARI
2     2020-07-01  15:32:57   D        EN-GB    TABLET    DOGS       ANIMALS     CHROME
3     2020-07-01  17:16:21   A        EN-CA    PC        SEATTLE    CITY        EDGE
4     2020-07-01  21:07:21   D        EN-GB    TABLET    DOG FOOD   ANIMAL      CHROME
5     2020-07-01  22:26:21   E        DE-DE    MOBILE    IPHONE     PRODUCTS    CHROME
```

And I am trying to get the last query for `userid`.

```
  last_query  
0        NaN  
1        NaN 
2        NaN 
3    WEATHER  
4       DOGS
5        NaN
```

I am using the following code to achieve the problem but I don't get any values.

```
s = pd.Series()
for name, value in df.groupby('userid'):
    userid = name
    last_query = value['query'].shift()
    s.append(last_query)
```

Is there any way to combine the values together or to achieve this at all?

Comment: Please also add that what values do you expect to see at the end.

Comment: Try `df.groupby('userid').max().reset_index()` , Also share the expected result else everything is assumption.

Comment: So you want to get the value of the `query` column for the previous timestamp separately each user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) and also you asked this again [pandas-select-another-column-using-the-result-from-groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296380/pandas-select-another-column-using-the-result-from-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df_last_queries = df.groupby('userid').shift(1)['query']
```

Result:

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3    WEATHER
4       DOGS
5        NaN
```

Important: The `time` column needs to be in ascending order (looks like this is the case).