# Pandas get max DateTime per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Team,
I have a simple dataframe with 2 columns(Datetime, Duration), Need to find what is the value of Duration on max Datetime value for each day. Below is the sample data for the dataframe

```
starttime             Duartion
2021-07-17 03:30:00   1234
2021-07-17 07:30:00   498
2021-07-18 03:30:00   1700
2021-07-18 07:40:00   2185
```

o/p

```
starttime             Duartion
2021-07-17 07:30:00   498
2021-07-18 07:40:00   2185
```

Any help on this please.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-requisite, using `datetime` type for "starttime":

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
```

If the "starttime" values are already sorted:

```
df.groupby(df['starttime'].dt.normalize(), as_index=False).last()
```

else:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df['starttime'].dt.normalize())['starttime'].idxmax().values]
```

Comment: Thanks mozway.. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This will take the maximum value per day:

```py
df.set_index('starttime').resample('1D').max()
```

Comment: he doesn't want the max `Duartion` but the `Duartion` for the max `starttime` per day