# max from a groupby[col].agg('max) inner vals

Tags: pandas, max, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I need to get max after agg('max') but I'm not succeeding.
my question on the data is:
For each defender_king print the battle in which he had the biggest defender_size

what i tried is:

```
battles.groupby(by=['defender_king','battle_number'])['defender_size'].agg('max')
```

and also:

```
battles.groupby(by=['defender_king','battle_number'])['defender_size'].max()
```

from this question:
[Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)-but it doesn't solve it-because of multiple selection of columns..(try it yourself and see)

but i get:

```
defender_king             battle_number
Balon/Euron Greyjoy       11                 900.0
                          13                   NaN
                          29                   NaN
                          31                 200.0
Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon  4                20000.0
                          5                 6000.0
                          6                12625.0
.
.
.
```

when what i want is:

```
defender_king             battle_number
    Balon/Euron Greyjoy       11                 900.0
    Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon  4                20000.0
.
```

only the max values from between all the values I get. Like max of max by column.

Comment: `battles.loc[battles.groupby(by=['defender_king','battle_number'])['defender_size'].idxmax()]`

Comment: did you try it? i tried with loc and iloc and i get an error for Nan's which i cant take off from some reason :(