# SQL two table query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

Players

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Maya |
| 3 | Carl |

Results

| ID | Player_ID | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 250 |
| 2 | 1 | 300 |
| 3 | 2 | 100 |
| 4 | 2 | 350 |
| 5 | 3 | 500 |

I want to select all the names from the table Players and the top scores of each person.
What I have so far:

```
SELECT Players.Name, max(Results.Result)
FROM Players JOIN Results
WHERE Players.ID = Results.Player_ID
```

But this only selects

| Carl | 500 |

and I want

| John  | 300 |

| Maya  | 350 |

| Carl  | 500 |

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause. (The current query is invalid and expected to raise an error.)

Comment: *"You need a GROUP BY clause. (The current query is invalid and expected to raise an error"* what jarth says is true this query is expected to give a error in the sql standards where this sql tag is about.. Are you using MySQL because MySQL allows this kind of invalid group by  queries without sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

try with a condition on the result : it needs to be the highest (max) for the player ID.

Try this:

`SELECT p.Name, r.result FROM Players p  JOIN Results r WHERE p.ID = r.Player_ID  and r.result = (select max(result) from results rr where rr.Player_ID = p.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY Players.ID, Players.Name` to your query. I added `Players.ID` in case two players have the same name:

```
SELECT Players.Name, max(Results.Result)
FROM Players JOIN Results
WHERE Players.ID = Results.Player_ID
GROUP BY Players.ID, Players.Name
```