# remain multiple rows with latest maintenance date - sort values and drop duplicate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have dataframe

```
df = {'id':['A','A','A','A','B','B'], 'type':['PO','PO','PO','MB','MB','FX'], 'desc':['01234','66666','77890','qwer','asdf','123abc'], 'maint_date':["2018-10-03","2018-10-03","2005-08-23", "2017-09-19","2008-08-13","2016-08-20"]}
```

| id | type | desc | maint_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | PO | 01234 | 2018-10-03 |
| A | PO | 66666 | 2018-10-03 |
| A | PO | 77890 | 2005-08-23 |
| A | MB | QWER | 2017-09-19 |
| B | MB | ASDF | 2008-08-13 |
| B | FX | 123ABC | 2016-08-20 |

I would like to sort based on latest 'id', 'type' and keeping the latest desc based on latest'maint_date'. I would like to keep multiple rows with the latest maintenance date even though having same 'id','type','maint_date'

To simplify, I would like to obtain result shown below:

| id | type | desc | maint_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | PO | 01234 | 2018-10-03 |
| A | PO | 66666 | 2018-10-03 |
| A | MB | QWER | 2017-09-19 |
| B | FX | 123ABC | 2016-08-20 |

Comment: @mkrieger1 df.sort_values(['id','type','maint_date'],ascending = [True,False,False]).drop_duplicates(['id','type','maint_date'],keep='first'), I tried to run this line of code, but it did not remain the second row with desc '6666' eventhough the maintenance date is the latest

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31185210/2901002) solution

Comment: thanks @jezrael, u led me straight to the right source! It finally solved my problem