# Get row which has max value in each group using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, finance, analysis

I have a dataframe. It is group by 'ex' as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKsho.png)
Now I want to get rows which have max value in each group

Comment: over which column?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to max value of transaction_fee column

Comment: I think you need df_2.groupby("ex")["transaction_fee"].max()

Comment: But I want to get the corresponding value in other columns of this max value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

so a quick google search and you will find out how to get relevant rows [here](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-groupby-maximum/):
for your implementation:

```py
df.groupby("ex")['transaction_fee'].max()
```

the other thing you should look for is how to get the corresponding indices for the original table. you could find something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby):

for your implemtionation:

```py
idxs = df.groupby("ex")['transaction_fee'].transform(max) == df['transaction_fee']
relevant_df = df[idxs]
```

cheers ✌