# Grouping Dataframe by Multiple Columns, and Then Dropping Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this (see table). For simplicity sake I've "aapl" is the only `ticker` shown. However, the real dataframe has more tickers.

| ticker | year | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aapl | 1999 | 1 |
| aapl | 2000 | 3 |
| aapl | 2000 | 2 |

What I'd like to do is first group the dataframe by `ticker`, then by `year`. Next, I'd like to remove any duplicate years. In the end the dataframe should look like this:

| ticker | year | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aapl | 1999 | 1 |
| aapl | 2000 | 3 |

I have a working solution, but it's not very "Pandas-esque", and involves `for` loops. I'm semi-certain that if I come back to the solution in three months, it'll be completely foreign to me.

Right now, I've been working on the following, with little luck:

```
df = df.groupby('ticker').groupby('year').drop_duplicates(subset=['year'])
```

This however, produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: wouldn't `df.drop_duplicates(['ticker', 'year'])` work?\

Comment: Your criteria for dropping the duplicated year is based on the highest return?

Comment: Alternatively, you can check on this post to see which method you would like to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208075/16836078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@QuangHoang provided the simplest version in the comments:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(['ticker', 'year'])
```

Alternatively, you can use `.groupby` twice, inside two [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)s:

```py
df.groupby("ticker", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: 
    x.groupby("year", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(['year']))
)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) function:

```py
df.groupby('ticker', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: 
    x[~x['year'].duplicated(keep='first')])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort the values first and then `groupby.tail`

```
df.sort_values('return').groupby(['ticker','year']).tail(1)

  ticker  year  return
0   aapl  1999       1
1   aapl  2000       3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure you want to do this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ticker","year"])
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzymN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).