# Create new dataframe from the highest values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe **`df`**:

```
    topic   num
0   a01     1
1   a01     1
2   a01     2
3   a02     1
4   a02     3
5   a02     2
6   a02     3
7   a03     2
8   a03     1
```

And I need to create a new dataframe **`newdf`**, where each row corresponds to the topic and the maximum number for each topic, like the following:

```
    topic   num
0   a01     2
1   a02     3
2   a03     2
```

I've tried to use the max() function from pandas, but to no avail. What I don't seem to get is how I'm gonna iterate through each row and find the highest value correspondent to the topic. How do I separate a01 from a02, so that I can get the maximum value for each? I've also tried transposing, but the same doubt keeps appearing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) with `numeric_only=True`:

```
newdf= df.groupby("topic", as_index=False).max(numeric_only=True)
```

##### Output:

```
print(newdf)

  topic  num
0   a01    2
1   a02    3
2   a03    2
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Example:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['topic'], sort=False)['num'].max()
```

Comment: yep, my mistake; should be 'num'. I just copied and half-heartedly modified it.