# Groupby maximum in Pandas dataframe while retaining other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Disclaimer: This is the first time I've worked with Pandas.

I have a data frame that looks something like this (no hierarchal index):

| State | Party | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | DEM | 46.67 |
| Alaska | IND | 37.29 |
| Alaska | LIB | 20 |
| Alaska | REP | 10 |
| Arizona | DEM | 46.5 |
| Arizona | REP | 49.5 |
| California | DEM | 42.65 |
| California | REP | 42.48 |
| etc. |  |  |

I would like the maximum percentage for each state, and the associated party for that state. So the output would look like for example:

| State | Party | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | DEM | 46.67 |
| Arizona | REP | 49.5 |
| California | DEM | 42.65 |
| etc. |  |  |

I have tried doing this:

```
# Isolate desired columns
df_h = pd.DataFrame(house_polls, columns=['state','party','pct'])
df_s = pd.DataFrame(senate_polls, columns=['state','party','pct'])

# Take the mean percent for state and party groups, and sort by said groups
cols = ["state", "party"]
df_h_avg = df_h.groupby(cols, as_index=False).mean(numeric_only=True).sort_values(by=cols)
df_s_avg = df_s.groupby(cols, as_index=False).mean(numeric_only=True).sort_values(by=cols)

# Take the maximum percent for each state
cols1 = ["state"]
house_results = df_h_avg.groupby(by=cols1).max(numeric_only=True)
senate_results = df_s_avg.groupby(by=cols1).max(numeric_only=True)

# Concatenate the associated party??
```

But it does not return the associated party.

| State | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Alaska | 46.67 |
| Arizona | 46.5 |
| California | 42.65 |
| etc. |  |

Comment: This is a duplicate, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Comment: Post linked by Joshua has several nice solutions to your problem. I personally prefer sort + groupby-last, but either will work

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one, the comment is added to the code.

```
#test data setup
df_raw="""
State,Party,Pct
Alaska,DEM,46.67
Alaska,IND,37.29
Alaska,LIB,20
Alaska,REP ,10
Arizona,DEM ,46.5
Arizona,REP,49.5
California,DEM ,42.65
California,REP ,42.48
"""
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_raw))
# group by State, and sort by Pct and get first row only
result=[e.sort_values('Pct',ascending=False)[:1] for e_name,e in df.groupby('State')]
merged_df = pd.concat(result)
merged_df.head(10) # store the results
```

result:

```
State       Party   Pct
Alaska      DEM     46.67
Arizona     REP     49.50
California  DEM     42.65
```

Summary: group by `State` , then sort by `Pct` and grab the first row only.

Comment: You could do that a bit neater: `df.sort_values("Pct", ascending=False).groupby("State", as_index=False).head(1)`

Comment: the `head(1)` is an abstraction for sure, the code behind the head is `return self.iloc[:n]`

Comment: I did use `.head(1)` because I can't use `.iloc[:1]` on a groupby object. My point was more that you can do it without going through a list and having to `concat`.