# Getting max values from multiple column groupby that has no qty column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRcGx.jpg)

My dataset has these columns : company, valuation, date joined, country, city, industry, continent, and year. I want to get the industry name and company number that has the highest number of company in each continent. I don't have number of company per industry per continent column because I don't think that's the right thing to do.

I already tried this code :
grouped_df = unicorn_df.groupby(['Continent','Industry']).count()
grouped_df

and here's the output I expected :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31vse.jpg)
I want an output that will show this :

Continent Industry Company
Africa Fintech 3
Asia E-commerce & direct-to-consumer 57
Europe Fintech 53
etc

What should I do next? Notice that here we need to count the company number first because it has no column with total company number per industry per continent.

Thank you so much!

Comment: For remove unnecessary columns use `grouped_df = unicorn_df.groupby(['Continent','Industry'])['Company'].count() `

Comment: Yes, but what I want to get is the industry that has highest number of company per continent. For example : Asia    Fintech    58, etc. How to do that?

Comment: Then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) solution

Comment: As I mentioned in my question above, I don't have specific column for the company number. I've read that solution before but the problem is a bit different with mine.

Comment: So not working `df = grouped_df.loc[grouped_df.groupby('Continent')['Company'].idxmax()]` ?

Comment: it works!!! thanks a bunch! however, i still don't really understand about that, will learn later. again, thanks!