# How to add non grouped column to the output of Pandas groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe df that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'student': ['Bob', 'Sally', 'Rich', 'Melissa', 'Len', 'Sue', 'Jon', 'Sandy',
                'William', 'Sara'],
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022],
    'gpa': [2.9, 3.7, 3.2, 3.8, 3.8, 3.1, 3.2, 2.7, 3.6, 3.9]})
df
```

Output:

```
   student  year  gpa
0      Bob  2020  2.9
1    Sally  2020  3.7
2     Rich  2020  3.2
3  Melissa  2021  3.8
4      Len  2021  3.8
5      Sue  2021  3.1
6      Jon  2021  3.2
7    Sandy  2022  2.7
8  William  2022  3.6
9     Sara  2022  3.9
```

I'd like to use `groupby()` to get the highest GPA per year ***and*** include the student associated with that GPA value.

The desired dataframe would look as follows:

```
year   gpa       student
2020   3.7       Sally
2021   3.8       Len
2021   3.8       Melissa     # <--- notice that there is a tie
2022   3.9       Sara
```

I tried using the following:

```
result = df.groupby(['year'])[['gpa']].max().reset_index()
result

    year    gpa
0   2020    3.7
1   2021    3.8
2   2022    3.9
```

But, this does not give me `student`.

How would I add `student` to the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate (I'm not sure if it's close enough): [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](/q/15705630/4518341)

Comment: `df.sort_values('gpa').drop_duplicates('year', keep='last')` is faster than groupby

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier to select the rows in the original dataframe that match the groupby max.

```
df[df.groupby('year')['gpa'].transform('max') == df['gpa']]
```

```
   student  year  gpa
1    Sally  2020  3.7
3  Melissa  2021  3.8
4      Len  2021  3.8
9     Sara  2022  3.9
```

This is based on [Zelazny7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705958/4518341) on [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705630/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.idxmax()`:

```py
out = df.groupby("year", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x["gpa"].idxmax()])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  student  year  gpa
0   Sally  2020  3.7
1     Len  2021  3.8
2    Sara  2022  3.9
```

---

Or:

```py
out = df.loc[df.groupby("year")["gpa"].idxmax()]
print(out)
```

---

EDIT: If there's a tie, you can do for example:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby("year")
    .apply(lambda x: x[x["gpa"] == x["gpa"].max()])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   student  year  gpa
0    Sally  2020  3.7
1  Melissa  2021  3.8
2      Len  2021  3.8
3     Sara  2022  3.9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find the maximum GPA per year

```
gpy_max = df.groupby('year')['gpa'].max().reset_index()
```

and then merge the result with the original DataFrame to get the corresponding student

```
result_df = gpy_max.merge(df, on=['year', 'gpa'], how='left')
print(result_df)
```

Output

```
0  2020  3.7    Sally
1  2021  3.8  Melissa
2  2021  3.8      Len
3  2022  3.9     Sara
```

Comment: You can simplify: `gpy_max.merge(df)`. It'll automatically use the intersection of the columns and do an inner join, which is equivalent to a left join in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think it that way.