# Merge duplicates dataframe with original dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset where I have to perform three tasks:
First, find all the duplicate rows based on columns A, B, C, D, E.
Second, within the duplicates, I need to check if value in col D = 'abc', in which case, value in column E changes to 0.
Then I need to find the max value of E, keep that as the first unique value and set the value of column E for all other duplicate rows as 0.
I then add a column 'change' to check which of the rows have had their values changed.

here is my code. My problem is that the exported dataframe only has the duplicate rows and i want the entire original dataframe with the changes applied.

````
#find duplicates
df1= df[df[['A' , 'B' ,'C' ,'D' ,'E']].duplicated()]
#change AUM value to 0 if STRUCTURE_REF_NO = RATE DEDUCTION
m1 = df1['D'].eq('abc')
df1.loc[m1, 'E'] = 0
#change AUM value of duplicates to 0
cols = ['A' , 'B' ,'C' ,'D' ,'E']
m2 = (df1.sort_values('E').duplicated(subset = cols)
      )
df1.loc[m2, 'E'] = 0
#add a column with remark if AUM value changed to 0
df1['change'] = m1 | m2
#export output csv
df1.to_csv('duplic.csv',index = False)```

How do i change the code so that i get the entire dataframe with the changes.
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, read notice([mre]) and please **provide input and desired output in text table.**
If you follow the request, you will get an answer very quickly. I hope this comment will help you who are struggling with coding.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't create df1 with only duplicated rows. But instead store it in another column to filter on later:
df['row_duplicated'] = df[['A' , 'B' ,'C' ,'D' ,'E']].duplicated()

```
m1 = df['duplicated'] & df['D'] == 'abc'
df.loc[m1, 'E'] = 0
```

Then to get the max, latest or whatever value for each duplicated E us a groupby method. A couple of options can be found here: [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

If you want a full code example you need to rephrase your question to include a reproducible example.