# Pandas GroupBy Two Text Columns And Return The Max Rows Based On Counts

Tags: python, pandas, max

I'm trying to figure out the max `(First_Word, Group)` pairs

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Word': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear'],
           'Group': ['apple bins', 'apple trees', 'orange juice', 'apple trees', 'pear tree'],
           'Text': ['where to buy apple bins', 'i see an apple tree', 'i like orange juice',
                'apple fell out of the tree', 'partrige in a pear tree']},
          columns=['First_Word', 'Group', 'Text'])

  First_Word         Group                        Text
0      apple    apple bins     where to buy apple bins
1      apple   apple trees         i see an apple tree
2     orange  orange juice         i like orange juice
3      apple   apple trees  apple fell out of the tree
4       pear     pear tree     partrige in a pear tree
```

Then I do a `groupby`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['First_Word', 'Group']).count()
                         Text
First_Word Group             
apple      apple bins       1
           apple trees      2
orange     orange juice     1
pear       pear tree        1
```

And I now want to filter it down to only unique index rows that have the max `Text` counts. Below you'll notice `apple bins` was removed because `apple trees` has the max value.

```
                         Text
First_Word Group             
apple      apple trees      2
orange     orange juice     1
pear       pear tree        1
```

This [max value of group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707746/python-how-can-i-get-rows-which-have-the-max-value-of-the-group-to-which-they) question is similar but when I try something like this:

```
df.groupby(["First_Word", "Group"]).count().apply(lambda t: t[t['Text']==t['Text'].max()])
```

I get an error: `KeyError: ('Text', 'occurred at index Text')`. If I add `axis=1` to the `apply` I get `IndexError: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index (apple, apple bins)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `grouped`, you now want to group by the `First Word` index level, and find the index labels of the maximum row for each group (using [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)):

```
In [39]: grouped.groupby(level='First_Word')['Text'].idxmax()
Out[39]: 
First_Word
apple       (apple, apple trees)
orange    (orange, orange juice)
pear           (pear, pear tree)
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

You can then use [`grouped.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select rows from `grouped` by index label:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'First_Word': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear'],
     'Group': ['apple bins', 'apple trees', 'orange juice', 'apple trees', 'pear tree'],
     'Text': ['where to buy apple bins', 'i see an apple tree', 'i like orange juice',
              'apple fell out of the tree', 'partrige in a pear tree']},
    columns=['First_Word', 'Group', 'Text'])

grouped = df.groupby(['First_Word', 'Group']).count()
result = grouped.loc[grouped.groupby(level='First_Word')['Text'].idxmax()]
print(result)
```

yields

```
                         Text
First_Word Group             
apple      apple trees      2
orange     orange juice     1
pear       pear tree        1
```