# Extract row with maximum value in a group pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

A similar question is asked here:
[Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-how-can-i-get-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-goups-making-groupby)

However, I just need one record per group even if there are more than one record with maximum value in that group.

In the example below, I need one record for "s2". For me it doesn't matter which one.

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'Sp':['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'Mt':['s1', 's1', 's2','s2','s2','s3'], 'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'count':[3,2,5,10,10,6]})
>>> df
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
1  s1  b      2      2
2  s2  c      3      5
3  s2  d      4     10
4  s2  e      5     10
5  s3  f      6      6
>>> idx = df.groupby(['Mt'])['count'].transform(max) == df['count']
>>> df[idx]
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
3  s2  d      4     10
4  s2  e      5     10
5  s3  f      6      6
>>>
```

Comment: This answer is the fastest solution I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21007047/778533

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `first`

```
In [14]: df.groupby('Mt').first()
Out[14]: 
   Sp  Value  count
Mt                 
s1  a      1      3
s2  c      3      5
s3  f      6      6
```

## Update

Set `as_index=False` to achieve your goal

```
In [28]: df.groupby('Mt', as_index=False).first()
Out[28]: 
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
1  s2  c      3      5
2  s3  f      6      6
```

## Update Again

Sorry for misunderstanding what you mean. You can sort it first if you want the one with max count in a group

```
In [196]: df.sort('count', ascending=False).groupby('Mt', as_index=False).first()
Out[196]: 
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
1  s2  e      5     10
2  s3  f      6      6
```

Comment: Thanks, the structure of the dataframe changed. How to get back the same structure (ie, num of rows and columns)

Comment: @user1140126 this one returns 5 instead of 10 for Mt = s2, I thought that you need max count in each row?

Comment: He said that it doesn't matter which one is his post

Comment: @waitingkuo I'm not native speaker, but for me `one record per group even if there are more than one record with maximum value in that group` means one record with maximum value even if there more than one record with this value. Looks like I was wrong :)

Comment: also, the title ot the question is `Extract row with maximum value in a group pandas dataframe` :)

Comment: Seems its my misunderstanding, I've updated my post, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How does this compare in speed to the other suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

To get first occurence of maximum `count` you can use [pandas.DataFrame.idxmax()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) function:

```
>>> df.iloc[df.groupby(['Mt']).apply(lambda x: x['count'].idxmax())]
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
3  s2  d      4     10
5  s3  f      6      6
```

Comment: How does this compare in speed to the other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Playing off of Roman Pekar's answer, I found that that the following code would work:

```
from math import isnan
df.iloc[[int(x) for x in df.groupby(by=df.Mt).apply(lambda x: x['count'].idxmax()).values if not isnan(y)]]
```

Note the isnan condition, as my application had some nan entries in the column we are maximizing over.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given don't show clearly what's by far the fastest option.
Sort by the row where you want the max value, and then drop duplicates (takes as parameter the name of the rows to take into account for evaluating duplicates)

```
df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Mt'])
```

NB : Yes that answer is already given in a comment on the question but it's very easy to miss it. And it will be up to 10 times faster as groupby.