# using indices with multiple values, how to get the smallest one

Tags: python, numpy

I have an index to choose elements from one array. But sometimes the index might have repeated entries... in that case I would like to choose the corresponding smaller value. Is it possible?

```
index = [0,3,5,5]
dist = [1,1,1,3]
arr = np.zeros(6)
arr[index] = dist
print arr
```

what I get:

```
[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  3.]
```

what I would like to get:

```
[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
```

**addendum**

Actually I have a third array with the (vector) values to be inserted. So the problem is to insert values from `values` into `arr` at positions `index` as in the following. However I want to choose the values corresponding to minimum `dist` when multiple values have the same index.

```
index = [0,3,5,5]
dist = [1,1,1,3]
values = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
arr = np.zeros((6,2))
arr[index] = values
print arr
```

I get:

```
 [[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 6.  7.]]
```

I would like to get:

```
 [[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 4.  5.]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closest" in your title?  Do you want the smallest of the values at a given index, or something else?

Comment: I wanted to say "smallest" but by some reason the title was considered invalid by stackoverflow :-(

Comment: How does `dist` affect the situation in the **addendum**?  My interpretation: "for a repeated number in `index`, choose the row in `values` that corresponds with the smallest number in `dist`".  Is that correct?  If you want the "smallest" value in `values` for the repeated indices, then it's ambiguous (if say the two rows in `values` are `[0, 2]` and `[1, 1]`)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. I want to insert values from `dist` and choose the one whose `dist` is minimum if multiple values have the same `index`

Comment: You want to insert values from `values` I thought.  My solution should do this for 2d `values`, by sorting with respect to `dist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
index = [0,3,5,5]
dist = [1,1,1,3]
s = pd.Series(dist).groupby(index).min()
arr = np.zeros(6)
arr[s.index] = s.values
print arr
```

Comment: Actually I have a third array for values... can you adapt your answer to the *addendum* in my question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't known why my addendum was missing... now you should find it with sample data.

Comment: I got the *addendum* part solved by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818756/extract-row-with-maximum-value-in-a-group-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

If `index` is sorted, then `itertools.groupby` could be used to group that list.

```
np.array([(g[0],min([x[1] for x in g[1]])) for g in 
    itertools.groupby(zip(index,dist),lambda x:x[0])])
```

produces

```
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [5, 1]])
```

This is about 8x slower than the version using `np.unique`.  So for `N=1000` is similar to the Pandas version (I'm guessing since something is screwy with my Pandas import).  For larger N the Pandas version is better.  Looks like the Pandas approach has a substantial startup cost, which limits its speed for small N.

Comment: Yeah, I found that timing too, I think making a `Series` must be expensive.