# Extract row with maximum value in DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: pandas

Newbie trying to break my addiction to excel.  I have a data set of paid invoices with the vendor and country where it was paid along with the amount.  I want know for each vendor, which country they have the greatest invoice amount and what percentage of their total business is in that country.  Using this data set I want the result to be:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMc5Z.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company' : ['bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
    'Country' : ['two','one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one'],
    'Amount' : [4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Pct' : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
CoCntry = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country'])
CoCntry.aggregate(np.sum)
```

After looking at multiple examples including: [Extract row with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818756/extract-row-with-maximum-value-in-a-group-pandas-dataframe) and [Getting max value using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818756/extract-row-with-maximum-value-in-a-group-pandas-dataframe)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818756/extract-row-with-maximum-value-in-a-group-pandas-dataframe): [Python : Getting the Row which has the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/python-getting-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby) I've gotten as far as creating a DataFrameGroupBy summarizing the invoice data by country.  I’m struggling with how to find the max row.  After which I must figure out how to calculate the percent.  Advice welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` `Pct` of summed values per groups by first level `Company`. Then filter `Dataframe` by max value per groups with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and last divide `Amount` column with `Series` `Pct`:

```
g = CoCntry.groupby(level='Company')['Amount']
Pct = g.transform('sum')
print (Pct)
Company  Country
bar      one        25
         three      25
         two        25
foo      one        28
         three      28
         two        28
Name: Amount, dtype: int64

CoCntry  = CoCntry.loc[g.idxmax()]
print (CoCntry)
                 Amount  Pct
Company Country             
bar     one          11    0
foo     two          11    0

CoCntry.Pct = CoCntry.Amount.div(Pct)
print (CoCntry.reset_index())
  Company Country  Amount       Pct
0     bar     one      11  0.440000
1     foo     two      11  0.392857
```

Similar another solution:

```
CoCntry = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country']).Amount.sum()
print (CoCntry)
Company  Country
bar      one        11
         three       4
         two        10
foo      one         9
         three       8
         two        11
Name: Amount, dtype: int64

g =  CoCntry.groupby(level='Company')
Pct = g.sum()
print (Pct)
Company
bar    25
foo    28
Name: Amount, dtype: int64

maxCoCntry  = CoCntry.loc[g.idxmax()].to_frame()
maxCoCntry['Pct'] = maxCoCntry.Amount.div(Pct, level=0)
print (maxCoCntry.reset_index())

  Company Country  Amount       Pct
0     bar     one      11  0.440000
1     foo     two      11  0.392857
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the statement "g = CoCntry.groupby(level='Company')['Amount']" triggers the error, "ttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: The second solution works great.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlbertJones - I am not sure what is problem, maybe need upgrade pandas - in `0.19.2` it works perfect.

Comment: The second solution is what I used.  I did not realize it, but a few of my records had $0 invoice amounts and your second solution was able to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company' : ['bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
    'Country' : ['two','one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one'],
    'Amount' : [4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    })
```

***solution***

```
# sum total invoice per country per company
comp_by_country = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country']).Amount.sum()

# sum total invoice per company
comp_totals = df.groupby('Company').Amount.sum()

# percent of per company per country invoice relative to company
comp_by_country_pct = comp_by_country.div(comp_totals).rename('Pct')
```

---

***answer to OP question***
Which `'Country'` has greatest total invoice for `'Company'` and what percentage of that companies total business.

```
comp_by_country_pct.loc[
    comp_by_country_pct.groupby(level=0).idxmax()
].reset_index()

  Company Country       Pct
0     bar     one  0.440000
1     foo     two  0.392857
```

---