# Return only rows with latest date from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (100 dates for 943 stocks) with date as index.
My aim is to create a smaller dataframe with each stock on the latest date

```
    adj_close   ticker  short_name
date            
2018-04-06  0.290   0001    SCOMNET
2018-04-05  0.300   0001    SCOMNET
2018-04-04  0.305   0001    SCOMNET
2018-04-03  0.340   0001    SCOMNET
2018-04-02  0.345   0001    SCOMNET
```

I tried filtering by using the max date but it only gave me the date and not the other columns...

```
klse_df[['adj_close','ticker','short_name']].index.max()

Timestamp('2018-04-06 00:00:00')
```

Comment: @miradulo - I think wrong dupe, it seems more complicated...

Comment: What is excepeted output?

Comment: @jezrael How so?

Comment: @jezael expected output is a reduced dataframe for all stocks with only the latest date

Comment: @miradulo - Not 100% sure, so ask OP for output.

Comment: @TimothyLombard - I understand, but in sample is only one stock? If there are 2 stocks (sample data only) can you add expected output? Thanks.

Comment: @miradulo  you mention this is a dup-  my issue is a bit different as the date is an index. will the same solution apply?

Comment: Yep! An easy solution is `df[df.index == max_date]` after finding `max_date` with `df.index.max()`.

Comment: @TimothyLombard - In my opinion need `df = df.sort_index().drop_duplicates('short_name', keep='last')` if `short_name` are `stock name`s

Comment: @miradulo - check comment above - why I think it is not dupe.

Comment: @jezrael You're assuming that he wants the most recent dated stock value for each stock. I don't think that's what his question is asking at the moment... but perhaps by divination you're right.

Comment: @miradulo - Ya, it is why ask OP for create expected output. I find this solution from question, second sentence `My aim is to create a smaller dataframe with each stock on the latest date`

Comment: @jezrael Added another dupe :)

Comment: @miradulo - hmmm, then it is close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007047/2901002).

Comment: establishing the latest date like:  last_date = klse_df.index.max()   then creating a new df  using this: ld_df = klse_df[klse_df.index == last_date] gave me the desired output.    Thank you @miradulo

Comment: @TimothyLombard No worries!

Comment: I'm kinda new here-  should dups be deleted?

Comment: @TimothyLombard Ehh nah, no real need to delete it - perhaps it could be a valuable sign-post for someone else.

Comment: something like: klse_df.groupby(['ticker'], sort=False).index.max()