# pandas: group and find most recent event from table, then join with existing table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables in pandas, a `user` table and a `history` table - the latter is essentially a log of all actions taken by users.

User table:

```
   |  user_id  |  source
0  |  1        |  blog
1  |  2        |  blog
2  |  3        |  organic
```

History table:

```
   |  user_id  |  action_type  |  t_actioned
0  |  1        |  332          |  2018-08-04 12:35:23   
1  |  1        |  453          |  2018-08-04 12:36:23   
2  |  1        |  332          |  2018-08-04 12:38:23   
3  |  2        |  452          |  2018-08-04 12:40:23   
4  |  3        |  523          |  2018-08-04 12:41:23   
5  |  2        |  452          |  2018-08-04 12:41:43
```

I'd like to find the timestamp of the latest action taken by each user, from the `history` table, and add it to the `user` table as a new column.

How can I do this?

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850954/pandas-get-most-recent-value-of-a-particular-column-indexed-by-another-column), I think it's something like:

```
 # Get the latest action by user
 first_action = history.group_by('user_id').agg(lambda df: df.sort('t_actioned')[-1:].values[0])
 user.first_action = # join with first_action somehow?
```

But the `agg` query doesn't work for me and I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First sort, drop duplicates and create a series from your history dataframe:

```
s = history.sort_values('t_actioned', ascending=False)\
           .drop_duplicates('user_id')\
           .set_index('user_id')['action_type']
```

Then map this to your user dataframe:

```
user['action_type'] = user['user_id'].map(s)
```

As pointed out in comments, if your log is already sorted, you can avoid `sort_values` and use `drop_duplicates('user_id', keep='last')`.

Comment: If you assume they are already sorted, you could also just do `drop_duplicates(keep='last')`

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that when construction a dictionary with multiple duplicate keys, you'll only keep the last one.

```
m = dict(history.sort_values('t_actioned').pipe(
    lambda d: zip(d.user_id, d.t_actioned)))

user.assign(latest=user.user_id.map(m))

   user_id   source               latest
0        1     blog  2018-08-04 12:38:23
1        2     blog  2018-08-04 12:41:43
2        3  organic  2018-08-04 12:41:23
```

---

The short version considering data is already sorted by `'t_actioned'`

```
user.assign(latest=user.user_id.map(dict(zip(history.user_id, history.t_actioned))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
history = history.groupby(['user_id']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('t_actioned', ascending = False))
history = history.drop_duplicates(subset = ['user_id'], keep = 'first')
user = pd.merge(user, history[['t_actioned']], on = 'user_id', how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
   user_id   source          t_actioned
0        1     blog 2018-08-04 12:38:23
1        2     blog 2018-08-04 12:41:43
2        3  organic 2018-08-04 12:41:23
```